# Find unique rows in numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

I need to find unique rows in a `numpy.array`.

For example:

```
>>> a # I have
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> new_a # I want to get to
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

I know that i can create a set and loop over the array, but I am looking for an efficient pure `numpy` solution. I believe that there is a way to set data type to void and then I could just use `numpy.unique`, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: pandas has a dataframe.drop_duplicates() method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322779/pandas-unique-dataframe and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in each row of a numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438438/removing-duplicates-in-each-row-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/8567929/3571 ?

Comment: @Andy Hayden, despite the title, it is not a duplicate to this question. codeape's link is a duplicate though.

Comment: This feature is coming natively to 1.13: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/7742

Answer (score 199, accepted):

As of NumPy 1.13, one can simply choose the axis for selection of unique values in any N-dim array. To get unique rows, use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) as follows:

```
unique_rows = np.unique(original_array, axis=0)
```

Comment: Careful with this function.  `np.unique(list_cor, axis=0)` gets you the _array with duplicate rows removed_; it does not filter the array to elements that _are unique in the original array_.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47562201/7954504), for example..

Comment: Note that if you want unique rows ignoring order of values in the row, you can sort the original array in the columns direct first: `original_array.sort(axis=1)`

Comment: I wish there was the equivalent of Pandas `drop_duplicates()`: it doesn't sort (uses an efficient hashing algorithm instead). Sorting is often unwanted, and incurs extra computation.

Answer (score 147):

Yet another possible solution

```
np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in a})
```

Edit: As others have mentioned this approach is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16. In modern versions you can do

```
np.vstack(tuple(set(map(tuple,a))))
```

Where `map(tuple,a)` makes every row of the matrix `a` hashable by making it them tuples. `set(map(tuple,a))` creates a set out of all of these unique rows. Sets are non-sequence iterables and as such cannot be directly used to construct NumPy arrays anymore. The outer call to `tuple` fixes this problem by converting the set to a tuple, making it acceptable for creating an array.

Comment: +1 This is clear, short and pythonic. Unless speed is a real issue, these type of solutions should take preference over the complex, higher voted answers to this question IMO.

Comment: Excellent! Curly braces or the set() function does the trick.

Comment: @Greg von Winckel Can you suggest something which doesn't something which doesn't change order.

Comment: Yes, but not in a single command:   x=[]; [x.append(tuple(r)) for r in a if tuple(r) not in x]; a_unique = array(x);

Comment: To avoid a FutureWarning, convert the set to a list like: `np.vstack(list({tuple(row) for row in AIPbiased[i, :, :]}))` 
FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.

Answer (score 115):

Another option to the use of structured arrays is using a view of a `void` type that joins the whole row into a single item:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))
_, idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)

unique_a = a[idx]

>>> unique_a
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

**EDIT**
Added `np.ascontiguousarray` following @seberg's recommendation. This will slow the method down if the array is not already contiguous.

**EDIT**
The above can be slightly sped up, perhaps at the cost of clarity, by doing:

```
unique_a = np.unique(b).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
```

Also, at least on my system, performance wise it is on par, or even better, than the lexsort method:

```
a = np.random.randint(2, size=(10000, 6))

%timeit np.unique(a.view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize*a.shape[1])))).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.17 ms per loop

%timeit ind = np.lexsort(a.T); a[np.concatenate(([True],np.any(a[ind[1:]]!=a[ind[:-1]],axis=1)))]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.93 ms per loop

a = np.random.randint(2, size=(10000, 100))

%timeit np.unique(a.view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize*a.shape[1])))).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
10 loops, best of 3: 29.9 ms per loop

%timeit ind = np.lexsort(a.T); a[np.concatenate(([True],np.any(a[ind[1:]]!=a[ind[:-1]],axis=1)))]
10 loops, best of 3: 116 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the answer that I was looking for, can you explain what is going on in this step: `b = a.view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))` ?

Comment: @Akavall It is creating a view of your data with a `np.void` data type of size the number of bytes in a full row. It´s similar two what you get if you have an array of `np.uint8`s and view it as `np.uint16`s, which combines every two columns into a single one, but more flexible.

Comment: This is slower, less flexible, and more memory intensive (`np.unique` creates a copy, as does `a[idx]`) than a lexsort-based method.

Comment: @Jaime, can you add a `np.ascontiguousarray` or similar to be generally safe (I know it is a bit more restrictive then necessary, but...). The rows *must* be contiguous for view to work as expected.

Comment: Interesting: I had assumed this would be equivalent to the structured array method, but it's actually significantly better, and does seem to do better than the lexsort method as well, especially for larger shape[1].

Comment: @ConstantineEvans It is a recent addition: in numpy 1.6, trying to run `np.unique` on an array of `np.void` returns an error related to mergesort not being implemented for that type. It works fine in 1.7 though.

Comment: Jaime and @ConstantineEvans. Do you know how to get column membership from any of the solutions that you presented? I started a new question based on these answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197071/find-unique-columns-and-column-membership

Comment: It's worth noting that if this method is used for floating point numbers there's a catch that `-0.` will not compare as equal to `+0.`, whereas an element-by-element comparison would have `-0.==+0.` (as specified by the ieee float standard).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782038/how-to-eliminate-the-extra-minus-sign-when-rounding-negative-numbers-towards-zer

Comment: @tom10 Yes, absolutely true. Then again, finding unique values in a floating point array is risky business anyway...

Comment: @ali_m My feeling is that the concerns were mostly about the interface, see [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2013-August/067443.html). There wasn't much enthusiasm on the list, because there rarely is much enthusiasm about anything that doesn't involve bashing `np.matrix`... ;-) I think Joe got discouraged a little too early, and wouldn't be surprised if something similar to that PR eventually made it into numpy.

Comment: In my case the first option (`...; unique_a = a[idx]`) performs actually faster: 4.8s vs 6.4s for shape (1.5e7, 2), consistent in two repeats

Comment: @DimaLituiev That's a surprising result... Calling `unique` with `return_index=True` should always be more expensive than doing it without, as it has to do extra work to compute the index array.  On top of that, you then have to use that index array to select some values from the original array. On the other side, the `.view` and `.reshape` operations should be virtually free, as they only affect array metadata.

Comment: unfortunately fails on `dtype= bool`

Comment: This is a great answer, but now since this functionality is built-in (in numpy 1.13), I have accepted a build-in solution answer, since at this point, using built-in would be the best approach to take.

Comment: Is there any benefit to this answer over the `axis` argument of `np.unique()`, now that that exists?

Answer (score 32):

If you want to avoid the memory expense of converting to a series of tuples or another similar data structure, you can exploit numpy's structured arrays.

The trick is to view your original array as a structured array where each item corresponds to a row of the original array.   This doesn't make a copy, and is quite efficient.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

ncols = data.shape[1]
dtype = data.dtype.descr * ncols
struct = data.view(dtype)

uniq = np.unique(struct)
uniq = uniq.view(data.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)
print uniq
```

---

To understand what's going on, have a look at the intermediary results.

Once we view things as a structured array, each element in the array is a row in your original array.  (Basically, it's a similar data structure to a list of tuples.)

```
In [71]: struct
Out[71]:
array([[(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)],
       [(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)],
       [(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)],
       [(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)],
       [(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8')])

In [72]: struct[0]
Out[72]:
array([(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8')])
```

Once we run `numpy.unique`, we'll get a structured array back:

```
In [73]: np.unique(struct)
Out[73]:
array([(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8')])
```

That we then need to view as a "normal" array (`_` stores the result of the last calculation in `ipython`, which is why you're seeing `_.view...`):

```
In [74]: _.view(data.dtype)
Out[74]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

And then reshape back into a 2D array (`-1` is a placeholder that tells numpy to calculate the correct number of rows, give the number of columns):

```
In [75]: _.reshape(-1, ncols)
Out[75]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

---

Obviously, if you wanted to be more concise, you could write it as:

```
import numpy as np

def unique_rows(data):
    uniq = np.unique(data.view(data.dtype.descr * data.shape[1]))
    return uniq.view(data.dtype).reshape(-1, data.shape[1])

data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
print unique_rows(data)
```

Which results in:

```
[[0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0]]
```

Comment: This actually seems very slow, almost as slow as using tuples. Sorting a structured array like this is slow, apparently.

Comment: @cge - Try it with larger-sized arrays. Yes, sorting a numpy array is slower than sorting a list. Speed isn't the main consideration in most cases where you're using ndarrays, though. It's memory usage.  A list of tuples will use _vastly_ more memory than this solution.  Even if you have enough memory, with a reasonably large array, converting it to a list of tuples has greater overhead than the speed advantage.

Comment: @cge - Ah, I didn't notice you were using `lexsort`. I thought you were referring to using a list of tuples.  Yeah, `lexsort` is probably the better option in this case. I'd forgotten about it, and jumped to an overly complex solution.

Answer (score 20):

`np.unique` when I run it on `np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10)` returns all the unique individual elements, but you want the unique rows, so first you need to put them into tuples:

```
array = #your numpy array of lists
new_array = [tuple(row) for row in array]
uniques = np.unique(new_array)
```

That is the only way I see you changing the types to do what you want, and I am not sure if the list iteration to change to tuples is okay with your "not looping through"

Comment: +1 This is clear, short and pythonic. Unless speed is a real issue, these type of solutions should take preference over the complex, higher voted answers to this question IMO.

Comment: I prefer this over the accepted solution.  Speed isn't an issue for me because I only have perhaps `< 100` rows per invocation.  This precisely describes how performing unique over rows is performed.

Comment: This actually does not work for my data, `uniques` contains unique elements. Potentially I misunderstand the expected shape of `array` - could you be more precise here?

Comment: @ryan-saxe I like that this is pythonic but this is not a good solution because the row returned to `uniques` are sorted (and therefore different from the rows in `array`).

`B = np.array([[1,2],[2,1]]);

A = np.unique([tuple(row) for row in B]);

print(A) = array([[1, 2],[1, 2]])`

Answer (score 19):

np.unique works by sorting a flattened array, then looking at whether each item is equal to the previous. This can be done manually without flattening:

```
ind = np.lexsort(a.T)
a[ind[np.concatenate(([True],np.any(a[ind[1:]]!=a[ind[:-1]],axis=1)))]]
```

This method does not use tuples, and should be much faster and simpler than other methods given here.

NOTE: A previous version of this did not have the ind right after a[, which mean that the wrong indices were used. Also, Joe Kington makes a good point that this *does* make a variety of intermediate copies. The following method makes fewer, by making a sorted copy and then using views of it:

```
b = a[np.lexsort(a.T)]
b[np.concatenate(([True], np.any(b[1:] != b[:-1],axis=1)))]
```

This is faster and uses less memory.

Also, if you want to find unique rows in an ndarray *regardless* of how many dimensions are in the array, the following will work:

```
b = a[lexsort(a.reshape((a.shape[0],-1)).T)];
b[np.concatenate(([True], np.any(b[1:]!=b[:-1],axis=tuple(range(1,a.ndim)))))]
```

An interesting remaining issue would be if you wanted to sort/unique along an arbitrary axis of an arbitrary-dimension array, something that would be more difficult.

Edit:

To demonstrate the speed differences, I ran a few tests in ipython of the three different methods described in the answers. With *your* exact a, there isn't too much of a difference, though this version is a bit faster:

```
In [87]: %timeit unique(a.view(dtype)).view('<i8')
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.4 us per loop

In [88]: %timeit ind = np.lexsort(a.T); a[np.concatenate(([True], np.any(a[ind[1:]]!= a[ind[:-1]], axis=1)))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.6 us per loop

In [89]: %timeit b = [tuple(row) for row in a]; np.unique(b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.6 us per loop
```

With a larger a, however, this version ends up being much, much faster:

```
In [96]: a = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10000,6))

In [97]: %timeit unique(a.view(dtype)).view('<i8')
10 loops, best of 3: 24.4 ms per loop

In [98]: %timeit b = [tuple(row) for row in a]; np.unique(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.2 ms per loop

In [99]: %timeit ind = np.lexsort(a.T); a[np.concatenate(([True],np.any(a[ind[1:]]!= a[ind[:-1]],axis=1)))]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.25 ms per loop
```

Comment: Very nice! On a side note, though, it does make several intermediary copies.  (e.g. `a[ind[1:]]` is a copy, etc)  On the other hand, your solution is generally 2-3x faster than mine up until you run out of ram.

Comment: Good point. As it turns out, my attempt to take out intermediary copies by using just the indexes made my method use more memory and end up slower than just making a sorted copy of the array, as a_sorted[1:] isn't a copy of a_sorted.

Comment: What is `dtype` in your timings? I think you got that one wrong. On my system, calling `np.unique` as described in my answer is slightly faster than using either of your two flavors of `np.lexsort`. And it is about 5x faster if the array to find uniques has shape `(10000, 100)`. Even if you decide to reimplement what `np.unique` does to trim some (minor) execution time, collapsing every row into a single object runs faster comparisons than having to call `np.any` on the comparison of the columns, especially for higher column counts.

Comment: @cge: you probably meant 'np.any' instead of standard 'any' wich does not take keyword argument.

Comment: @Jaime - I believe `dtype` is just `a.dtype`, i.e. the data type of the data being viewed, as is was done by Joe Kington in his answer. If there are many columns, another (imperfect!) way to keep things fast using `lexsort` is to only sort on a few columns. This is data-specific as one needs to know which columns provide enough variance to sort perfectly. E.g. `a.shape = (60000, 500)` - sort on the first 3 columns: `ind = np.lexsort((a[:, 2], a[:, 1], a[:, 0]))`. The time savings are fairly substantial, but the disclaimer again: it might not catch all cases - it depends on the data.

Answer (score 12):

I've compared the suggested alternative for speed and found that, surprisingly, the void view `unique` solution is even a bit faster than numpy's native `unique` with the `axis` argument. If you're looking for speed, you'll want

```py
numpy.unique(
    a.view(numpy.dtype((numpy.void, a.dtype.itemsize*a.shape[1])))
).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
```

I've implemented that fastest variant in [npx.unique_rows](https://github.com/nschloe/npx#unique_rows).

There is [a bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11136) for this, too.

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy
import perfplot


def unique_void_view(a):
    return (
        numpy.unique(a.view(numpy.dtype((numpy.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))))
        .view(a.dtype)
        .reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
    )


def lexsort(a):
    ind = numpy.lexsort(a.T)
    return a[
        ind[numpy.concatenate(([True], numpy.any(a[ind[1:]] != a[ind[:-1]], axis=1)))]
    ]


def vstack(a):
    return numpy.vstack([tuple(row) for row in a])


def unique_axis(a):
    return numpy.unique(a, axis=0)


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: numpy.random.randint(2, size=(n, 20)),
    kernels=[unique_void_view, lexsort, vstack, unique_axis],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(15)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
    equality_check=None,
)
```

Comment: Very nice answer, one minor point: `vstack_dict`, never uses a dict, curly braces is a set comprehension, and therefore its behavior is nearly identical to `vstatck_set`. Since, `vstack_dict` performance line is missing for fro graph, it looks like it is just being covered by `vstack_set` performance graph, since they are so similar!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've improved the plot to include only one `vstack` variant.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another variation for @Greg pythonic answer

```
np.vstack(set(map(tuple, a)))
```

Answer (score 8):

I didn’t like any of these answers because none handle floating-point arrays in a linear algebra or vector space sense, where two rows being “equal” means “within some ”. The one answer that has a tolerance threshold, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26867764/500207, took the threshold to be both element-wise and *decimal* precision, which works for some cases but isn’t as mathematically general as a true vector distance.

Here’s my version:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist

def uniqueRows(arr, thresh=0.0, metric='euclidean'):
    "Returns subset of rows that are unique, in terms of Euclidean distance"
    distances = squareform(pdist(arr, metric=metric))
    idxset = {tuple(np.nonzero(v)[0]) for v in distances <= thresh}
    return arr[[x[0] for x in idxset]]

# With this, unique columns are super-easy:
def uniqueColumns(arr, *args, **kwargs):
    return uniqueRows(arr.T, *args, **kwargs)
```

The public-domain function above uses [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to find the Euclidean (customizable) distance between *each pair* of rows. Then it compares each each distance to a `thresh`old to find the rows that are within `thresh` of each other, and returns just one row from each `thresh`-cluster.

As hinted, the distance `metric` needn’t be Euclidean—`pdist` can compute sundry distances including `cityblock` (Manhattan-norm) and `cosine` (the angle between vectors).

If `thresh=0` (the default), then rows have to be bit-exact to be considered “unique”. Other good values for `thresh` use scaled machine-precision, i.e., `thresh=np.spacing(1)*1e3`.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks. It is the most (mathematically) generalized answer written so far. It considers a matrix as a set of data points or samples in the N-dimensional space and find a collection of same or similar points (similarity being defined by either Euclidean distance or by any other methods). These points can be overlapping data points or very close neighborhoods. At the end, a collection of same or similar points are replaced by any of the point (in the above answer by a first point) belonging to the same set. This helps to reduce redundancy from a point cloud.

Comment: @Sanchit aha, that’s a good point, instead of picking the “first” point (actually it could be effectively random, since it depends on how Python stores the points in a `set`) as representative of each `thresh`-sized neighborhood, the function could allow the user to specify how to pick that point, e.g., use the “median” or the point closest to the centroid, etc.

Comment: Sure. No doubt. I just mentioned the first point since this is what your program is doing which is completely fine.

Comment: Just a correction—I wrongly said above that the row that would be picked for each `thresh`-cluster would be random because of the unordered nature of `set`. Of course that’s a brainfart on my part, the `set` stores tuples of indexes that are in the `thresh`-neighborhood, so this `findRows` *does* in fact return, for each `thresh`-cluster, the first row in it.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `drop_duplicates` from pandas:

```
>>> timeit pd.DataFrame(image.reshape(-1,3)).drop_duplicates().values
1 loops, best of 3: 3.08 s per loop

>>> timeit np.vstack({tuple(r) for r in image.reshape(-1,3)})
1 loops, best of 3: 51 s per loop
```

Comment: I actually love this answer. Sure, it doesn't use numpy directly, but to me it's the one that's easiest to understand while being fast.

Answer (score 3):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) wraps the solution posted by Jaime in a nice and tested interface, plus many more features:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
new_a = npi.unique(a)  # unique elements over axis=0 (rows) by default
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer in this page I have written a function that replicates the capability of MATLAB's `unique(input,'rows')` function, with the additional feature to accept tolerance for checking the uniqueness. It also returns the indices such that `c = data[ia,:]` and `data = c[ic,:]`. Please report if you see any discrepancies or errors.

```
def unique_rows(data, prec=5):
    import numpy as np
    d_r = np.fix(data * 10 ** prec) / 10 ** prec + 0.0
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(d_r).view(np.dtype((np.void, d_r.dtype.itemsize * d_r.shape[1])))
    _, ia = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
    _, ic = np.unique(b, return_inverse=True)
    return np.unique(b).view(d_r.dtype).reshape(-1, d_r.shape[1]), ia, ic
```

Answer (score 1):

Beyond @Jaime excellent answer, another way to collapse a row is to uses `a.strides[0]` (assuming `a` is C-contiguous) which is equal to `a.dtype.itemsize*a.shape[0]`. Furthermore `void(n)` is a shortcut for `dtype((void,n))`. we arrive finally to this shortest version :

```
a[unique(a.view(void(a.strides[0])),1)[1]]
```

For

```
[[0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

np.unique works given a list of tuples:

```
>>> np.unique([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (2, 2)])
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

With a list of lists it raises a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: doesn't seem to work on mine. Each tuple is two strings instead of two float numbers

Comment: does not work, it return a list of elements not tuples

Answer (score 0):

For general purpose like 3D or higher multidimensional nested arrays, try this:

```
import numpy as np

def unique_nested_arrays(ar):
    origin_shape = ar.shape
    origin_dtype = ar.dtype
    ar = ar.reshape(origin_shape[0], np.prod(origin_shape[1:]))
    ar = np.ascontiguousarray(ar)
    unique_ar = np.unique(ar.view([('', origin_dtype)]*np.prod(origin_shape[1:])))
    return unique_ar.view(origin_dtype).reshape((unique_ar.shape[0], ) + origin_shape[1:])
```

which satisfies your 2D dataset:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
unique_nested_arrays(a)
```

gives:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

But also 3D arrays like:

```
b = np.array([[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]],
              [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
              [[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]],
              [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]])
unique_nested_arrays(b)
```

gives:

```
array([[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
   [[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]],
   [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]])
```

Comment: Using the `unique` `return_index` as Jaime does should make that last `return` line simpler.  Just index the orginal `ar` on the right axis.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. I'm assuming as my unique rows contained strings and not numbers. However this answer from another thread did work:

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38461043/5402386

You can use .count() and .index() list's methods

```
coor = np.array([[10, 10], [12, 9], [10, 5], [12, 9]])
coor_tuple = [tuple(x) for x in coor]
unique_coor = sorted(set(coor_tuple), key=lambda x: coor_tuple.index(x))
unique_count = [coor_tuple.count(x) for x in unique_coor]
unique_index = [coor_tuple.index(x) for x in unique_coor]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can actually turn m x n numeric numpy array into m x 1 numpy string array, please try using the following function, it provides **count**, **inverse_idx** and etc, just like numpy.unique:

```
import numpy as np

def uniqueRow(a):
    #This function turn m x n numpy array into m x 1 numpy array storing 
    #string, and so the np.unique can be used

    #Input: an m x n numpy array (a)
    #Output unique m' x n numpy array (unique), inverse_indx, and counts 

    s = np.chararray((a.shape[0],1))
    s[:] = '-'

    b = (a).astype(np.str)

    s2 = np.expand_dims(b[:,0],axis=1) + s + np.expand_dims(b[:,1],axis=1)

    n = a.shape[1] - 2    

    for i in range(0,n):
         s2 = s2 + s + np.expand_dims(b[:,i+2],axis=1)

    s3, idx, inv_, c = np.unique(s2,return_index = True,  return_inverse = True, return_counts = True)

    return a[idx], inv_, c
```

Example:

```
A = np.array([[ 3.17   9.502  3.291],
  [ 9.984  2.773  6.852],
  [ 1.172  8.885  4.258],
  [ 9.73   7.518  3.227],
  [ 8.113  9.563  9.117],
  [ 9.984  2.773  6.852],
  [ 9.73   7.518  3.227]])

B, inv_, c = uniqueRow(A)

Results:

B:
[[ 1.172  8.885  4.258]
[ 3.17   9.502  3.291]
[ 8.113  9.563  9.117]
[ 9.73   7.518  3.227]
[ 9.984  2.773  6.852]]

inv_:
[3 4 1 0 2 4 0]

c:
[2 1 1 1 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets get the entire numpy matrix as a list, then drop duplicates from this list, and finally return our unique list back into a numpy matrix:

```
matrix_as_list=data.tolist() 
matrix_as_list:
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]

uniq_list=list()
uniq_list.append(matrix_as_list[0])

[uniq_list.append(item) for item in matrix_as_list if item not in uniq_list]

unique_matrix=np.array(uniq_list)
unique_matrix:
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score -3):

The most straightforward solution is to make the rows a single item by making them strings. Each row then can be  compared as a whole for its uniqueness using numpy. This solution is generalize-able you just need to reshape and transpose your array for other combinations. Here is the solution for the problem provided.

```
import numpy as np

original = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

uniques, index = np.unique([str(i) for i in original], return_index=True)
cleaned = original[index]
print(cleaned)
```

Will Give:

```
 array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Send my nobel prize in the mail

Comment: Very inefficient and error prone, e.g. with different print options. The other options are clearly preferable.

Answer (score -3):

```
import numpy as np
original = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
# create a view that the subarray as tuple and return unique indeies.
_, unique_index = np.unique(original.view(original.dtype.descr * original.shape[1]),
                            return_index=True)
# get unique set
print(original[unique_index])
```