# Comparison with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 files (1 old and 1 new) that have the same structure that I need to compare and then return data that is unique to the new list.

Each file is TAB delimited and looks something like this (each about 16k lines long):

```
8445    200807
8345    200807
ect.    ect.
```

I have a basic understanding of doing comparisons using a loop, but I'm not sure how to compare corresponding columns of data against 2 other corresponding columns.

EDIT: Sorry, there is some confusion on what I want as the result. So if I this as my old file:

```
8445    200807
8345    200807
```

And this is my new file:

```
8445    200807
8445    200809
```

I want the script to return:

```
8445    200809
```

So the pair has to be unique to the new file. If that makes sense.

Comment: What should the comparison do? And what is the expected result, a list of common records?

Comment: do you really need to use python? diff seems well suited already (or perhaps `diff | sort | uniq`)

Comment: you can read using `numpy.loadtxt` and then use the [procedure explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16970982/832621) to keep only the unique rows...

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Why `8445    200809` and not the other entry?

Comment: "kick out" can mean either "remove" or "return", unfortunately..

Comment: @DSM: I need to "return" sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @m0ngr31 And how are you choosing between the entries?

Comment: @Marcin I need the unique pairs from the new file to return.

Comment: @m0ngr31 Both `8445    200807` and 
`8445    200809` are unique pairs, but you only want to return one. Why is that?

Comment: I updated it again to be more clear. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Marcin: 8445 200807 is in the old file as well, so I don't need it in the new one.

Comment: I am nominating this for reopening as it is now clear.

Comment: However, what part of this task has you stumped? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to do it. I am not the world's best python expert in the world if you know what I mean.

Comment: So `comm -13 file1 file2` in Python, basically (and relaxing the constraint that `comm` requires sorted input)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the most straight forward way I can think of. Purists will probably complain it does not use a with statement, so be warned.

```
def compare_files()
    f1 = open('old')
    f2 = open('new')

    d1 = set()

    for line in f1:
        d1.add(line)

    for line in f2:
        if not line in d1:
            yield line
```

And use it like this:

```
 for line in compare_files():
     print "not in old", line,
```

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear about what I'm trying to get out of it.

Comment: I have updated my answer, to match your comments, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess what you want: a set of rows that are common to both files. That's the intersection of the two files, i.e.

```
with open("file1") as f1, open("file2") as f2:
    rows1 = set(ln.split() for ln in f1)
    rows2 = set(ln.split() for ln in f2)

    for row in rows1 & rows2:
        print("\t".join(row))
```

This changes the order of the rows, though. If you want the lines that only occur in the first file, then replace `&` with `-`.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear about what I'm trying to get out of it.

Comment: @m0ngr31: that's `rows2 - rows1`.