# Element-wise maximum of two sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there an easy/build-in way to get the element-wise maximum of two (or ideally more) sparse matrices? I.e. a sparse equivalent of [np.maximum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'element-wise'?  If I go to the sparse coo_matrix page I see functions like `arcsin() Element-wise arcsin.`  But no `max`.  Do you want the largest value in each matrix; largest along some dimension; largest across the set of matrices?

Comment: No offense, but I think element-wise is pretty unambiguous. In: two matrices A, B with the same dimensions. Out: A matrix C where C[i,j] = max(A[i,j], B[i,j])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
def maximum (A, B):
    BisBigger = A-B
    BisBigger.data = np.where(BisBigger.data < 0, 1, 0)
    return A - A.multiply(BisBigger) + B.multiply(BisBigger)
```

Comment: Counterexample: `A = coo_matrix([1,1]); B = coo_matrix([0,2]); maximum(A, B).A` gives `array([[0, 2]])`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no built-in way to do this in `scipy.sparse`. The easy solution is

```
np.maximum(X.A, Y.A)
```

but this is obviously going to be very memory-intensive when the matrices have large dimensions and it might crash your machine. A memory-efficient (but by no means fast) solution is

```
# convert to COO, if necessary
X = X.tocoo()
Y = Y.tocoo()

Xdict = dict(((i, j), v) for i, j, v in zip(X.row, X.col, X.data))
Ydict = dict(((i, j), v) for i, j, v in zip(Y.row, Y.col, Y.data))

keys = list(set(Xdict.iterkeys()).union(Ydict.iterkeys()))

XmaxY = [max(Xdict.get((i, j), 0), Ydict.get((i, j), 0)) for i, j in keys]
XmaxY = coo_matrix((XmaxY, zip(*keys)))
```

Note that this uses pure Python instead of vectorized idioms. You can try shaving some of the running time off by vectorizing parts of it.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned I tried that before and it crashed my MacBook, because I did not have enough disk space for the swap file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another memory-efficient solution that should be a bit quicker than larsmans'. It's based on finding the set of unique indices for the nonzero elements in the two arrays using code from [Jaime's excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/1461210).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def sparsemax(X, Y):

    # the indices of all non-zero elements in both arrays
    idx = np.hstack((X.nonzero(), Y.nonzero()))

    # find the set of unique non-zero indices
    idx = tuple(unique_rows(idx.T).T)

    # take the element-wise max over only these indices
    X[idx] = np.maximum(X[idx].A, Y[idx].A)

    return X

def unique_rows(a):
    void_type = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(void_type)
    idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)[1]
    return a[idx]
```

Testing:

```
def setup(n=1000, fmt='csr'):
    return sparse.rand(n, n, format=fmt), sparse.rand(n, n, format=fmt)

X, Y = setup()
Z = sparsemax(X, Y)
print np.all(Z.A == np.maximum(X.A, Y.A))
# True

%%timeit X, Y = setup()
sparsemax(X, Y)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.92 ms per loop
```

Comment: Ah, forget about it - Maarten's solution is many orders of magnitude quicker than mine!

Answer (score 1):

The latest `scipy` (13.0) defines element-wise booleans for sparse matricies. So:

```
BisBigger = B>A
A - A.multiply(BisBigger) + B.multiply(BisBigger)
```

`np.maximum` does not (yet) work because it uses `np.where`, which is still trying to get the `truth value of an array`.

Curiously `B>A` returns a boolean dtype, while `B>=A` is float64.

Comment: Too bad scipy 13.0 is not in PyPi yet.

Comment: I am not sure what `B>=A` does. But if it would do what you'd except it to do and you have two very sparse matrices A and B, you'd get a very dense matrix as a result.

Comment: Good point.  It explains the warning I get: `"SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using >= and <= is inefficient, try using <, >, or !=, instead."`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that returns a sparse matrix that is element-wise maximum of two sparse matrices. It implements the answer by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj):

```
def sparse_max(A, B):
    """
    Return the element-wise maximum of sparse matrices `A` and `B`.
    """
    AgtB = (A > B).astype(int)
    M = AgtB.multiply(A - B) + B
    return M
```

Testing:

```
A = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.randint(-9,10, 25).reshape((5,5))) 
B = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.randint(-9,10, 25).reshape((5,5)))

M = sparse_max(A, B)
M2 = sparse_max(B, A)

# Test symmetry:
print((M.A == M2.A).all())
# Test that M is larger or equal to A and B, element-wise:
print((M.A >= A.A).all())
print((M.A >= B.A).all())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy import sparse
from numpy import array
I = array([0,3,1,0])
J = array([0,3,1,2])
V = array([4,5,7,9])
A = sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)),shape=(4,4))

A.data.max()
9
```

If you haven't already, you should try out [ipython](http://ipython.org/), you could have saved your self time my making your spare matrix `A` then simply typing `A.` then tab, this will print a list of methods that you can call on `A`. From this you would see `A.data` gives you the non-zero entries as an array and hence you just want the maximum of this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but you misunderstood the question. I edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: By element wise you mean, of matrix A and B which has the larger maximum element?

Comment: Then unless your array's are extremely large I would just convert them to arrays 'A.toarray()' and use this method. If they are extremely large and this breaks your computer then I have no idea sorry.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for getting the element-wise max of two matrices, and even for the max of one matrix it's incorrect: what if the max of `.data` is negative?

Answer (score 0):

On the current SciPy you may use the object method [`maximum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.maximum.html):

```py
mM = mA.maximum(mB)
```