# How to speed up matrix code

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have the following simple code which estimates the probability that an h by n binary matrix has a certain property.  It runs in exponential time (which is bad to start with) but I am surprised it is so slow even for n = 12 and h = 9.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import itertools

n = 12
h = 9

F = np.matrix(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat = n))).transpose()

count = 0
iters = 100
for i in xrange(iters):
    M =  np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n))
    product = np.dot(M,F)
    setofcols = set()
    for column in product.T:
        setofcols.add(repr(column))
    if (len(setofcols)==2**n):
        count = count + 1
print count*1.0/iters
```

I have profiled it using n = 10 and h = 7. The output is rather long but here are the lines that took more time.

```
        23447867 function calls (23038179 primitive calls) in 35.785 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.002    0.001    0.019    0.010 __init__.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.054    0.054 __init__.py:106(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.022    0.022 __init__.py:15(<module>)
        2    0.003    0.002    0.013    0.006 __init__.py:2(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.003    0.003 __init__.py:38(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 __init__.py:4(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.004    0.004 __init__.py:45(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.002    0.002 __init__.py:88(<module>)
   307200    0.306    0.000    1.584    0.000 _methods.py:24(_any)
   102400    0.026    0.000    0.026    0.000 arrayprint.py:22(product)
   102400    1.345    0.000   32.795    0.000 arrayprint.py:225(_array2string)
307200/102400    1.166    0.000   33.350    0.000 arrayprint.py:335(array2string)
   716800    0.820    0.000    1.162    0.000 arrayprint.py:448(_extendLine)
204800/102400    1.699    0.000    5.090    0.000 arrayprint.py:456(_formatArray)
   307200    0.651    0.000   22.510    0.000 arrayprint.py:524(__init__)
   307200   11.783    0.000   21.859    0.000 arrayprint.py:538(fillFormat)
  1353748    1.920    0.000    2.537    0.000 arrayprint.py:627(_digits)
   102400    0.576    0.000    2.523    0.000 arrayprint.py:636(__init__)
   716800    2.159    0.000    2.159    0.000 arrayprint.py:649(__call__)
   307200    0.099    0.000    0.099    0.000 arrayprint.py:658(__init__)
   102400    0.163    0.000    0.225    0.000 arrayprint.py:686(__init__)
   102400    0.307    0.000   13.784    0.000 arrayprint.py:697(__init__)
   102400    0.110    0.000    0.110    0.000 arrayprint.py:713(__init__)
   102400    0.043    0.000    0.043    0.000 arrayprint.py:741(__init__)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.003    0.003 chebyshev.py:87(<module>)
        2    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 collections.py:284(namedtuple)
        1    0.277    0.277   35.786   35.786 counterfeit.py:3(<module>)
   205002    0.222    0.000    0.247    0.000 defmatrix.py:279(__array_finalize__)
   102500    0.747    0.000    1.077    0.000 defmatrix.py:301(__getitem__)
   102400    0.322    0.000   34.236    0.000 defmatrix.py:352(__repr__)
   102400    0.100    0.000    0.508    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1087(ravel)
   307200    0.382    0.000    2.829    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1563(any)
      271    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 function_base.py:3220(add_newdoc)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.003    0.003 hermite.py:59(<module>)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.003    0.003 hermite_e.py:59(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.002    0.002 index_tricks.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.003    0.003 laguerre.py:59(<module>)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.003    0.003 legendre.py:83(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 linalg.py:10(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 numeric.py:1(<module>)
   102400    0.247    0.000   33.598    0.000 numeric.py:1365(array_repr)
   204800    0.321    0.000    1.143    0.000 numeric.py:1437(array_str)
   614400    1.199    0.000    2.627    0.000 numeric.py:2178(seterr)
   614400    0.837    0.000    0.918    0.000 numeric.py:2274(geterr)
   102400    0.081    0.000    0.186    0.000 numeric.py:252(asarray)
   307200    0.259    0.000    0.622    0.000 numeric.py:322(asanyarray)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.004    0.004 polynomial.py:54(<module>)
   513130    0.134    0.000    0.134    0.000 {isinstance}
   307229    0.075    0.000    0.075    0.000 {issubclass}
5985327/5985305    0.595    0.000    0.595    0.000 {len}
 306988    0.120    0.000    0.120    0.000 {max}
   102400    0.061    0.000    0.061    0.000 {method '__array__' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   102406    0.027    0.000    0.027    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
   307200    0.241    0.000    1.824    0.000 {method 'any' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   307200    0.482    0.000    0.482    0.000 {method 'compress' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   204800    0.035    0.000    0.035    0.000 {method 'item' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   102451    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
   102400    0.222    0.000    0.222    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   921176    3.330    0.000    3.330    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
   102405    0.057    0.000    0.057    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
  2992167    0.660    0.000    0.660    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
   102400    0.041    0.000    0.041    0.000 {method 'splitlines' of 'str' objects}
        6    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.001 {method 'sub' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
   307276    0.090    0.000    0.090    0.000 {min}
      100    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {numpy.core._dotblas.dot}
   409639    0.473    0.000    0.473    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
  1228800    0.239    0.000    0.239    0.000 {numpy.core.umath.geterrobj}
   614401    0.352    0.000    0.352    0.000 {numpy.core.umath.seterrobj}
   102475    0.031    0.000    0.031    0.000 {range}
   102400    0.076    0.000    0.102    0.000 {reduce}
204845/102445    0.198    0.000   34.333    0.000 {repr}
```

The multiplication of the matrices seems to take a tiny fraction of the  time. Is it possible to speed up the rest?

**Results**

There are now three answers but one seems to have a bug currently. I have tested the remaining two with n=18, h=11 and iters=10 .

- bubble - 21 seconds, 185MB of RAM . 16 seconds on "sort".
- hpaulj - 7.5 seconds, 130MB of RAM . 3 seconds on "tolist". 1.5 seconds on "numpy.core.multiarray.array", 1.5 seconds on "genexpr" (the 'set' line).

Interestingly, the time for multiplying the matrices is still a tiny fraction of the overall time taken.

Comment: obviously it is possible to speed it up incredulously. if you see arrayprint, which part do you think is the slow part ;).

Comment: You should read the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array I mentioned in your previous question for much more efficient method of uniques count. `arrapyprint.fillFormat` is what called in `repr(column)` part of your code, so it's the slowest part.

Comment: The set approach might be very good. But if you know the dtype/row is safe (including contiguity and byte order), you could just use `arr.tostring()`.

Comment: Most of the time is in `arrayprint`, which is called by `repr`.  What's the purpose of converting the numbers to strings?  `numpy` is designed to work rapidly with arrays of numbers.  When dealing with strings it uses regular Python methods.

Comment: @hpaulj The conversion is just so you can tell how many columns are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `repr(col)` with

```
setofcols.add(tuple(column.A1.tolist()))
```

`set` accepts a `tuple`. `column.A1` is the matrix converted to a 1d array.  The tuple is then something like `(0, 1, 0)`, which `set` can easily compare.

Just replacing the expensive `repr` formatting lops off a lot of time (25x speedup).

EDIT

By creating and filling the `set` in one statement I get a further 10x speed up.  In my tests it is 2x faster than `bubble's` vectorization.

```
count = 0
for i in xrange(iters):
    M =  np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n))
    product = np.dot(M,F)
    setofcols = set(tuple(x) for x in product.T.tolist())
    # or {tuple(x) for x in product.T.tolist()} if new enough Python
    if (len(setofcols)==2**n):
        count += 1
        # print M # to see the unique M
print count*1.0/iters
```

EDIT

Here's something even faster - transform each column of 9 integers into 1, using `dot([1,10,100,...],column)`.  Then apply `np.unique` (or `set`) to the list of integers.  It's a 2-3x further speedup.

```
count = 0
X = 10**np.arange(h)
for i in xrange(iters):
    M =  np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n))
    product = np.dot(M,F)
    setofcols = np.unique(np.dot(X,product).A1)
    if (setofcols.size==2**n):
        count += 1
print count*1.0/iters
```

With this the top calls are

```
  200    0.201    0.001    0.204    0.001 {numpy.core._dotblas.dot}
  100    0.026    0.000    0.026    0.000 {method 'sort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
  100    0.007    0.000    0.035    0.000 arraysetops.py:93(unique)
```

Comment: Thanks. It still spends a small percentage of the time multiplying the matrices. I get for different parameters of n and h and iters=2, "39    6.465    0.166    6.465    0.166 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}", "2    3.803    1.902    3.803    1.902 {method 'tolist' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}", "2    1.072    0.536    1.072    0.536 {numpy.core._dotblas.dot}"

Comment: `np.dot` usng BLAS is one the most efficient (time wise) operations in `numpy`.  So I'm not surprised that `tolist` takes longer.  I suspect the numerous `array` calls remain even if you remove the `set` operations.

Comment: Profiling in IPython shows that `multiarray.array` is being called while generating `F`, not during the `iters` loop.

Comment: I've gotten further speedup by compressing each column down to one integer (by multiplying by `[1,10,100,...]`).  Still have to do `unique` or `set` column by column.

Answer (score 3):

To speed up the code above you should avoid loops.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def unique_rows(a):
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    unique_a = np.unique(a.view([('', a.dtype)]*a.shape[1]))
    return unique_a.view(a.dtype).reshape((unique_a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))


n = 12
h = 9
iters=100
F = np.matrix(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat = n))).transpose()
M =  np.random.randint(2, size=(h*iters,n))
product = np.dot(M,F)
counts = map(lambda x: len(unique_rows(x.T))==2**n, np.split(product,iters,axis=0))
prob=float(sum(counts))/iters

#All unique submatrices M (hxn) with the sophisticated property...
[np.split(M,iters,axis=0)[j] for j in range(len(counts)) if counts[j]==True]
```

Comment: the bottleneck in code **is** slow unique_rows implementation.

Comment: These solutions are slow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array

Comment: Nope, those links I refer to too, but your answer do not contain them in any way, so it adds no value to OP question

Comment: If you care to elaborate your answer to working code, I guess it gonna be accepted.

Comment: @Bubble Thanks! This is much faster. Avoiding loops has two problems though. The first is that it now uses a lot of RAM. The second is that I can't now print M when the number of distinct columns is 2**n. Is there an easy way to modify your code to fix this?

Comment: Thanks. I may have to make it back into a loop to increase iters but that is a very nice solution.

Comment: `map` is a hidden loop.

Answer (score 1):

As alko and seberg pointed out, you are loosing a lot of time converting your arrays to large strings to store them in your set of columns.

If I understood your code correctly, you are trying to find if the number of different columns in your `product` matrix is equal to the length of this matrix. You can do that easily by sorting it and looking at differences from one column to the next:

```
D = (np.diff(np.sort(product.T, axis=0), axis=0) == 0)
```

This will give you a matrix of booleans `D`. You can then see whether at least one element changes from one column to the next:

```
C = (1 - np.prod(D, axis=1)) # i.e. 'not all(D[i,:]) for all i'
```

You then simply have to take see whether `all` the values are different:

```
hasproperty = np.all(C)
```

Which gives you the complete code:

```
def f(n, h, iters):
    F = np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=n))).T
    counts = []
    for _ in xrange(iters):
        M = np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n))
        product = M.dot(F)
        D = (np.diff(np.sort(product.T, axis=1), axis=0) == 0)
        C =  (1 - np.prod(D, axis=1))
        hasproperty = np.all(C)
        counts.append(1. if hasproperty else 0.)
    return np.mean(counts)
```

Which takes roughly 8s for `f(12, 9, 100)`.

If you prefer comically compact expressions:

```
def g(n, h, iters):
    F = np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=n))).T
    return np.mean([np.all(1 - np.prod(np.diff(np.sort(np.random.randint(2,size=(h,n)).dot(F).T, axis=1), axis=0)==0, axis=1)) for _ in xrange(iters)])
```

Timing it gives:

```
>>> setup = """import numpy as np
def g(n, h, iters):
    F = np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=n))).T
    return np.mean([np.all(1 - np.prod(np.diff(np.sort(np.random.randint(2,size=(h,n)).dot(F).T, axis=1), axis=0)==0, axis=1)) for _ in xrange(iters)])
"""
>>> timeit.timeit('g(10, 7, 100)', setup=setup, number=10)
17.358669997900734
>>> timeit.timeit('g(10, 7, 100)', setup=setup, number=50)
83.06966196163967
```

Or approximatively 1.7s per call to `g(10,7,100)`.

Comment: Thanks but I think there is something slightly wrong with f at least. When you do f(12,8,100) you get 0.0.  But using @bubble's code you don't.

Comment: Indeed, there was a bug: `product.T` had to be sorted along `axis=1`. This is corrected, thank's for your feedback :)

Comment: I am afraid there is still a bug. Try n =5, h = 4 and iters = 100. The output should be roughly 0.07.