# Python: Counting identical rows in an array (without any imports)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

For example, given:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to get a 3-dimensional array, looking like:

```
result = array([[[ 2.,  0.],
                 [ 0.,  2.]],

                [[ 0.,  2.],
                 [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

One way is:

```
for row in data
    newArray[ row[0] ][ row[1] ][ row[2] ] += 1
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
for i in dimension1
   for j in dimension2
      for k in dimension3
          result[i,j,k] = (data[data[data[:,0]==i, 1]==j, 2]==k).sum()
```

This doesn't seem to work and I would like to achieve the desired result by sticking to my implementation rather than the one mentioned in the beginning (or using any extra imports, eg counter).

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you are using numpy.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, will fix it. Regardless, any ideas?

Comment: I think your first approach is easier to read and certainly faster.

Comment: @tobias_k I know! I'm just curious to see why the second approach isn't working :)

Comment: Please post syntactically correct code next time

Comment: BTW, you could also simplify your first solution to just `for row in data: newArray[tuple(row)] += 1`, but I guess Ashwini's solution is still better. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `data[data[data[:,0]==i, 1]==j, 2]==k` is not what you expect it to be.

Let's take this apart for the case `(i,j,k) == (0,0,0)`

`data[:,0]==0` is `[True, True, False, False, True, True]`, and `data[data[:,0]==0]` correctly gives us the lines where the first number is `0`.

Now *from those lines* we get the lines where the second number is `0`: `data[data[:,0]==0, 1]==0`, which gives us `[True, False, False, True]`. And this is the problem. Because if we take those indices from `data`, i.e., `data[data[data[:,0]==0, 1]==0]` we do not get the rows where the first and second number are `0`, but the `0th` and `3rd` row instead:

```
In [51]: data[data[data[:,0]==0, 1]==0]
Out[51]: array([[0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1]])
```

And if we now filter for the rows where the third number is `0`, we get the wrong result w.r.t. the orignal data.

And that's why your approach does not work. For better methods, see the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`numpy.histogramdd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html) for this:

```
>>> np.histogramdd(data, bins=(2, 2, 2))[0]
array([[[ 2.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following

```
#Get output dimension and construct output array.
>>> dshape = tuple(data.max(axis=0)+1)
>>> dshape
(2, 2, 2)
>>> out = np.zeros(shape)
```

If you have numpy 1.8+:

```
out.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(data.T, dshape)]+=1
```

Else:

```
#Get indices and unique the resulting array
>>> inds = np.ravel_multi_index(data.T, dshape)
>>> inds, inverse = np.unique(inds, return_inverse=True)
>>> values = np.bincount(inverse)

>>> values
array([2, 2, 2])

>>> out.flat[inds] = values
>>> out
array([[[ 2.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

Numpy versions before numpy 1.7 do not have a `add.at` attribute and the top code will not work without it. As `ravel_multi_index` may not be the fastest algorithm ever you can look into taking the [unique rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array) of a numpy array. In effect these two operations should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fear the imports. They're what make Python awesome.

If question assumes that you already have the result matrix.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0]]
)
result = np.zeros((2,2,2))

# range of each dim, aka allowable values for each dim
dim_ranges = zip(np.zeros(result.ndim), np.array(result.shape)-1)
dim_ranges
# Out[]:
#     [(0.0, 2), (0.0, 2), (0.0, 2)]

# Multidimentional histogram will effectively "count" along each dim
sums,_ = np.histogramdd(data,bins=result.shape,range=dim_ranges)
result += sums
result
# Out[]:
#     array([[[ 2.,  0.],
#             [ 0.,  2.]],
#
#            [[ 0.,  2.],
#             [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

This solution solves for any "result" ndarray, no matter what the shape. Additionally, it works fine even if your "data" ndarray has indices which are out-of-bounds for your result matrix.