# Numpy find indices of matching columns

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a large 2xn array A and a smaller 2xn array B.  All columns in B can be found in A.  I'm looking to find the indices of A by matching columns in B.  For example,

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([
    [101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 211],
    [102, 103, 105, 104, 106, 109, 224, 109, 110, 110, 108, 109, 110, 211, 212, 211, 212, 213]
])

B = numpy.array([
    [101, 103, 109],
    [102, 224, 212]
])
```

The answer that I'm looking for is [0,6,14].  Interested to know if there is an efficient way rather than looping.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint: numpy arrays support column slicing. Check [this](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, given the arrays are pre-sorted:

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([
    [101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 211],
    [102, 103, 105, 104, 106, 109, 224, 109, 110, 110, 108, 109, 110, 211, 212, 211, 212, 213]
])

B = numpy.array([
    [101, 103, 109],
    [102, 224, 212]
])

def search2D(A, B):
    to_find_and_bounds = zip(
        B[1],
        numpy.searchsorted(A[0], B[0], side="left"),
        numpy.searchsorted(A[0], B[0], side="right")
    ) 

    for to_find, left, right in to_find_and_bounds:
        offset = numpy.searchsorted(A[1, left:right], to_find)
        yield offset + left

list(search2D(A, B))
#>>> [0, 6, 14]
```

This is `O(len B · log len A)`.

For unsorted arrays, you can perform an indirect sort:

```
sorter = numpy.lexsort(A[::-1])
sorted_copy = A.T[sorter].T

sorter[list(search2D(sorted_copy, B))]
#>>> array([ 3,  6, 14])
```

If you need multiple results from one index, try

```
for to_find, left, right in to_find_and_bounds:
    offset_left = numpy.searchsorted(A[1, left:right], to_find, side="left")
    offset_right = numpy.searchsorted(A[1, left:right], to_find, side="right")
    yield from range(offset_left + left, offset_right + left)
```

Comment: @sorry, I had just deleted the comment seeing your edit

Comment: Thanks @Veedrac!  This is very helpful.  Being a novice, could you advise what changes are required if both arrays are 1D?

Comment: @sgoh If both are 1D, just `for _, left, right in to_find_and_bounds: yield from range(left, right)`.

Answer (score 4):

There is hardly a good answer for your problem: numpy is not very well suited for this type of problems, although it can be done. To do subarray searches, if your dtype is not floating point, the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array/16973510#16973510) is probably your best bet. You would start with something like:

```
AA = np.ascontiguousarray(A.T)
BB = np.ascontiguousarray(B.T)

dt = np.dtype((np.void, AA.dtype.itemsize * AA.shape[1]))
AA = AA.view(dt).ravel()
BB = BB.view(dt).ravel()
```

And now it is just about searching for the items in a 1D array in another 1D array, which is pretty straightforward, assuming there are no repeated columns in the original `A` array.

If either of your arrays is really small, as in your example, it is going to be hard to beat something like:

```
indices = np.argmax(AA == BB[:, None], axis = 1)
```

But for larger datasets, it is going to be hard to beat a sorting approach:

```
sorter = np.argsort(AA)
sorted_indices = np.searchsorted(AA, BB, sorter=sorter)
indices = sorter[sorted_indices]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, my arrays are not too big but there may be repeated columns.

Comment: Do you need to know where does each column of `B` come up in `A`? Or do you simply need to know which columns of `A` are also in `B`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string-based comparison such as this one using `np.char.array`

```
ca = np.char.array(a)[0,:] + np.char.array(a)[1,:]
cb = np.char.array(b)[0,:] + np.char.array(b)[1,:]
np.where(np.in1d(ca, cb))[0]
#array([ 0,  6, 14], dtype=int64)
```

---

EDIT:

you can also manipulate the array `dtype` in order to transform the `a` array to one with `shape=(18,)` where each element contains the data of the two elements of the corresponding column. The same idea can be applied to array `b`, obtaining `shape=(3,)`. Then you use `np.where(np.in1d())` to get the indices:

```
nrows = a.shape[0]
ta = np.ascontiguousarray(a.T).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.itemsize*nrows))).flatten()
tb = np.ascontiguousarray(b.T).view(np.dtype((np.void, b.itemsize*nrows))).flatten()
np.where(np.in1d(ta, tb))[0]
#array([ 0,  6, 14], dtype=int64)
```

The idea is similar to the string-based approach.

Comment: With `np.in1d` you lose track of which column of `B` corresponds to which column of `A`. This may not be a requirement of the OP, but it is worth noting.

Comment: @Jaime thank you... as you said, for what the OP needs `np.in1d()` is more straightforward

Comment: Thanks @SaulloCastro, you have given me some good ideas to explore.

Answer (score -2):

Numpy has all you need. I assume the arrays are not sorted, conversly you can improve the following code as you prefer:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 211],
     [102, 103, 105, 104, 106, 109, 224, 109, 110, 110, 108, 109, 110, 211, 212, 211, 212, 213]])
b = np.array([[101, 103, 109],
     [102, 224, 212]])

idxs = []

for i in range(np.shape(b)[1]):
    for j in range(np.shape(a)[1]):
        if np.array_equal(b[:,i],a[:,j]):
            idxs.append(j)

print idxs
```

Comment: This is not a numpy solution, you could do the same with simple python lists as input.

Comment: Plus this is `O(n²)` and slow.

Comment: Read above: "I assume arrays are not sorted". I cannot avoid O(n^2).

Comment: Sorting is `O(n log n)`, so no, you can.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in this way indices change on both arrays.