# Unique colours in stack of images (4d numpy array)

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I have a stack of RGB images in a 4d numpy array, so the shape is
(n_images, height, width, n_channels) where n_channels is 3. 
How can I get a list of unique RGB values across all the images.

I found this question [numpy: unique list of colors in the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780697/numpy-unique-list-of-colors-in-the-image) for a single image but want to apply it to my stack of images without a for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.unique and set the axis, to look across the images. so basically it will look for unique pixel values.

i am reusing the answer from link you shared for your scenario.

```
np.unique(img.reshape(-1, img.shape[3]), axis=0)
```

The above code will result in an array of shape (unique_pixels_len,3)

The original answer had img.shape[2] i.e. the channels and in your case it is img.shape[3] which represents the channels.