# How to test if all rows are distinct in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, is there a nice idiomatic way of testing if all rows are distinct in a 2d array?

I thought I could do

```
len(np.unique(arr)) == len(arr)
```

but this doesn't work at all.  For example,

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,4]])
np.unique(arr)
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array is about FINDING the unique row, OP is about TESTING if the rows are all unique. Different questions.

Comment: Several interesting answers to how to drop nonunique rows/columns: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2011-December/031193.html. You can then just see if the reduced array is the same as the original.  If you use pandas, there is an efficient implementation to do such a thing.

Comment: @GWW Isn't the question different as CT Zhu pointed out?

Comment: Finding Unique rows would essentially be the same thing as seeing if each row is unique.

Comment: @GWW I think the point is the answer in the linked question might be overkill for the testing problem. In other words there might be a simpler and faster solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the correlation matrix and ask if *only* the diagonal elements are `1`:

```
(np.corrcoef(M)==1).sum()==M.shape[0]


In [66]:

M = np.random.random((5,8))
In [72]:

(np.corrcoef(M)==1).sum()==M.shape[0]
Out[72]:
True
```

This if you want to do a similar thing for the columns:

`(np.corrcoef(M, rowvar=0)==1).sum()==M.shape[1]`

or without `numpy` at all:

```
len(set(map(tuple,M)))==len(M)
```

Fiter out the unique rows and then test if the resultant is same as `M` is an overkill:

```
In [99]:

%%timeit

b = np.ascontiguousarray(M).view(np.dtype((np.void, M.dtype.itemsize * M.shape[1])))
_, idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)

unique_M = M[idx]

unique_M.shape==M.shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 54.6 µs per loop
In [100]:

%timeit len(set(map(tuple,M)))==len(M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It's surprising that a non-numpy way is the fastest. Doesn't it have to convert numpy array -> tuple -> set ?

Comment: Pure python FTW!  If there are many more rows than cols, can try  `len(set(tuple(zip(*M.T)))) == len(M)` it might be faster.