# Count how many times each row is present in numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to count a number each row shows in a `np.array`, for example:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1], # duplicate of row 0
                     [9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                     [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1], # duplicate of row 0
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Row `[1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1]` shows up 3 times.

A simple naive solution would involve converting all my rows to tuples, and applying `collections.Counter`, like this:

```
from collections import Counter
def row_counter(my_array):
    list_of_tups = [tuple(ele) for ele in my_array]
    return Counter(list_of_tups)
```

Which yields:

```
In [2]: row_counter(my_array)
Out[2]: Counter({(1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1): 3, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0): 1, (9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1): 1, (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0): 1})
```

However, I am concerned about the efficiency of my approach. And maybe there is a library that provides a built-in way of doing this. I tagged the question as `pandas` because I think that `pandas` might have the tool I am looking for.

Comment: I like this problem! You may be able to use `np.lexsort` to your advantage, but I am not sure whether the collection after sorting can be done fast enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [the answer to this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array/16973510#16973510) to get the counts of the unique items.

In numpy 1.9 there is a `return_counts` optional keyword argument, so you can simply do:

```
>>> my_array
array([[1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> dt = np.dtype((np.void, my_array.dtype.itemsize * my_array.shape[1]))
>>> b = np.ascontiguousarray(my_array).view(dt)
>>> unq, cnt = np.unique(b, return_counts=True)
>>> unq = unq.view(my_array.dtype).reshape(-1, my_array.shape[1])
>>> unq
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1]])
>>> cnt
array([1, 1, 3, 1])
```

In earlier versions, you can do it as:

```
>>> unq, _ = np.unique(b, return_inverse=True)
>>> cnt = np.bincount(_)
>>> unq = unq.view(my_array.dtype).reshape(-1, my_array.shape[1])
>>> unq
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1]])
>>> cnt
array([1, 1, 3, 1])
```

Comment: The last reshape can be simplified a bit with: `unq.view((my_array.dtype, my_array.shape[1]))`; it uses the same sort of multi-item dtype as the first `view`.

Comment: Does this have a benefit over `np.unique` with `axis` parameter?  (Which may have been added after this question was written)

Comment: I keep getting a type error "This axis arguement is unique is not supported for dtype object". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15):

I think just specifying `axis` in `np.unique` gives what you need.

```
import numpy as np
unq, cnt = np.unique(my_array, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

Note: this feature is available only in `numpy>=1.13.0`.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution for ```numpy>=1.13.0```.

Answer (score 5):

(This assumes that the array is fairly small, e.g. fewer than 1000 rows.)

Here's a short NumPy way to count how many times each row appears in an array:

```
>>> (my_array[:, np.newaxis] == my_array).all(axis=2).sum(axis=1)
array([3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1])
```

This counts how many times each row appears in `my_array`, returning an array where the first value shows how many times the first row appears, the second value shows how many times the second row appears, and so on.

Comment: With `n=np.arange(my_array.shape[0])` one can obtain a nice result also by writing  `[n[ui] for ui in (my_array[:,np.newaxis,:] == my_array).all(axis=2)]`... Nice answer, I've have already half understood it, but what puzzles me it's how you come out with the solution!

Answer (score 3):

A pandas approach might look like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_array,columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6'])
df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']).size()
```

Note: supplying column names is not necessary

Comment: i have no idea why this got downvoted. This is a good example of how to do this using Pandas.

Comment: Can you show how you would do it without supplying columns names?

Comment: Just omit the columns arg in the DataFrame() and use [0,1,2,3,4,5] in the group by().  [0,1,2,3,4,5] will the default column names that pandas assigns.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, I was trying to pass `np.arange(6)`, and that was not giving me what I wanted, but passing a list works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You solution is not bad, but if your matrix is large you will probably want to use a more efficient hash (compared to the default one Counter uses) for the rows before counting. You can do that with [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.hash.html):

```
A = np.random.rand(5, 10000)

%timeit (A[:,np.newaxis,:] == A).all(axis=2).sum(axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop

%timeit Counter(joblib.hash(row) for row in A).values()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop

%timeit Counter(tuple(ele) for ele in A).values()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.75 ms per loop

%timeit pd.DataFrame(A).groupby(range(A.shape[1])).size()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.24 s per loop
```

The pandas solution is extremely slow (about 2s per loop) with this many columns. For a small matrix like the one you showed your method is faster than joblib hashing but slower than numpy:

```
numpy: 100000 loops, best of 3: 15.1 µs per loop
joblib:1000 loops, best of 3: 885 µs per loop
tuple: 10000 loops, best of 3: 27 µs per loop
pandas: 100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop
```

If you have a large number of rows then you can probably find a better substitute for Counter to find hash frequencies.

**Edit**: Added numpy benchmarks from @acjr's solution in my system so that it is easier to compare. The numpy solution is the fastest one in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

A solution identical to Jaime's can be found in the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author)

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.count(my_array)
```