# Counting how many times a row occurs in a matrix (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a better way to count how many times a given row appears in a numpy 2D array than

```
def get_count(array_2d, row):
    count = 0
    # iterate over rows, compare
    for r in array_2d[:,]:
        if np.equal(r, row).all():
            count += 1
    return count    

# let's make sure it works

array_2d = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
row = np.array([1,2])       

count = get_count(array_2d, row)
assert(count == 1)
```

Comment: If this code works, it should be on Code Review; not here.

Comment: Also related: [Count how many times each row is present in numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000092/count-how-many-times-each-row-is-present-in-numpy-array)

Comment: @Carcigenicate, questions like this that (implicitly) ask for ways to replace loops with faster numpy methods are quite common on SO.  It's very much a 'how to' kind of question.   These questions do get asked on CR, but that forum is pickier as to presentation, and the `numpy` community is much smaller there.  CR is better for code style review.  I like working code on SO, it makes it easier to test my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(array_2d == row).all(-1).sum()
```

---

Considering memory efficiency, here's one approach considering each row from `array_2d` as an indexing tuple on an `n-dimensional` grid and assuming positive numbers in the inputs -

```
dims = np.maximum(array_2d.max(0),row) + 1
array_1d = np.ravel_multi_index(array_2d.T,dims)
row_scalar = np.ravel_multi_index(row,dims)
count = (array_1d==row_scalar).sum()
```

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674038/3293881)'s a post discussing the various aspects related to it.

**Note:** Using `np.count_nonzero` could be much faster to count booleans instead of summation with `.sum()`. So, do consider using it for both the above mentioned aproaches.

Here's a quick runtime test -

```
In [74]: arr = np.random.rand(10000)>0.5

In [75]: %timeit arr.sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.6 µs per loop

In [76]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(arr)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 µs per loop
```

Comment: `(array_2d == row).all(-1).sum()` is _exactly_ what I was looking for. Wasn't aware of `all()` params.