# Calculate saturated values after clipping in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I am using theano.clip to limit values of my numpy array. For e.g.

```
array = np.array([[  1.,  -1.,  -3.,   1.,   1.],
         [  3.,  -4.,  -5.,   0.,  -1.],
         [  8.,  -3.,  -7.,  -3.,  -3.],
         [  8.,   2.,  -2.,  -3.,  -3.],
         [  7.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.]])

max_val = np.array([2.0]).astype('float32')

T.clip(array, -max_val, max_val).eval()
```

***Output:***

```
array([[ 1., -1., -2.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2., -2., -2.,  0., -1.],
       [ 2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 2.,  2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

I want to calculate how many values were clipped after the clipping operation. Is it possible?

Comment: After or before, if in anyway it's possible. I need to limit the values but for stats purpose I need to calc how much data is lost after clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`np.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) on a mask of values beyond the limits computed with comparison against the min and max limits -

```
np.count_nonzero((array < -max_val) | (array > max_val))
```

`np.count_nonzero` is meant for performance, as it operates on a mask/boolean array to get the total count [`pretty efficiently`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38687313/3293881).

Alternatively, a shorter version using absolute values as the min and max limits as in this case they are just negative and positive values of the same limiting number -

```
np.count_nonzero(np.abs(array) > max_val)
```

Sample run -

```
In [267]: array
Out[267]: 
array([[ 1., -1., -3.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 3., -4., -5.,  0., -1.],
       [ 8., -3., -7., -3., -3.],
       [ 8.,  2., -2., -3., -3.],
       [ 7.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])

In [268]: max_val = np.array([2.0]).astype('float32')

In [269]: np.count_nonzero((array < -max_val) | (array > max_val))
Out[269]: 13

In [270]: np.count_nonzero(np.abs(array) > max_val)
Out[270]: 13
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I am using "where" `array[np.where(abs(array) > max_val)]` at the moment. Which one you think will be much faster?

Comment: @blackbug Don't use `np.where`. Directly use the mask : `array[abs(array) > max_val]`. But that gives you the elements themselves, not the count, so that's a different thing than counting the number of clipped elements.

Answer (score 1):

If your array's name is `a`, you can do

```
np.logical_or(a >= 1, a <= -1).sum()
```

You won't count elements twice, since `- max_val < max_val`. However, this requires two passes on `a`.