# Row frequency in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, frequency

Having a numpy  array  for example `a=np.array([[1,1,2],[7,8,5],[1,1,3],[1,1,2]])`
I am intersted to retrieve  in a  fast  way the number of occurences of each  row. [1,1,2] =>2 etc.
I  have done some implementation using  lists, but  on   real data sets  the computation  time is very  long.
Is there  a method   to do  it    faster   , potentially  using only  numpy as  data structure?

Comment: Also relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000092/count-how-many-times-each-row-is-present-in-numpy-array