# Ignoring duplicate entries in sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, duplicates, sparse-matrix

I've tried to initialize `csc_matrix` and `csr_matrix` from a list of `(data, (rows, cols))` values as the documentation suggests.

```
sparse = csc_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(n, n))
```

The problem is that, the method that I actually have for generating the `data`, `rows` and `cols` vectors introduces duplicates for some points. By default, scipy adds the values of the duplicate entries. However, in my case, those duplicates have exactly the same value in `data` for a given `(row, col)`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make scipy ignore the second entry if already exists one, instead of adding them.

Ignoring the fact that I could improve the generation algorithm to avoid generating duplicates, is there a parameter or another way of creating a sparse matrix that ignores duplicates?

Currently two entries with `data = [4, 4]; cols = [1, 1]; rows = [1, 1];` generate a sparse matrix which value at `(1,1)` is `8` while the desired value is `4`.

```
>>> c = csc_matrix(([4, 4], ([1,1],[1,1])), shape=(3,3))
>>> c.todense()
matrix([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]])
```

I'm also aware that I could filter them by using a 2-dimensional numpy `unique` function, but lists are quite large so this is not really a valid option.

Other possible answer to the question: Is there any way of specifying what to do with duplicates? i.e. keeping the `min` or `max` instead of the default `sum`?

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer is no, there is no built-in way of changing the behavior for duplicates. You shouldn't be too quick on discarding the use of `np.unique` though: no matter how large your lists are, scipy is going to convert them to arrays and do similar operations under the hood, so there is no reason why you shouldn't attempt to.

Comment: `np.unique` is 1d, so handling these 2d coordinates will require some extra effort.

Comment: True, but tricks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array) make it 2D.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating an intermediary `dok` matrix works in your example:

```
In [410]: c=sparse.coo_matrix((data, (cols, rows)),shape=(3,3)).todok().tocsc()

In [411]: c.A
Out[411]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

A `coo` matrix puts your input arrays into its `data`,`col`,`row` attributes without change.  The summing doesn't occur until it is converted to a `csc`.

`todok` loads the dictionary directly from the `coo` attributes.  It creates the blank `dok` matrix, and fills it with:

```
dok.update(izip(izip(self.row,self.col),self.data))
```

So if there are duplicate `(row,col)` values, it's the last one that remains.  This uses the standard Python dictionary hashing to find the unique keys.

---

Here's a way of using `np.unique`.  I had to construct a special object array, because `unique` operates on 1d, and we have a 2d indexing.

```
In [479]: data, cols, rows = [np.array(j) for j in [[1,4,2,4,1],[0,1,1,1,2],[0,1,2,1,1]]]

In [480]: x=np.zeros(cols.shape,dtype=object)

In [481]: x[:]=list(zip(rows,cols))

In [482]: x
Out[482]: array([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)], dtype=object)

In [483]: i=np.unique(x,return_index=True)[1]

In [484]: i
Out[484]: array([0, 1, 4, 2], dtype=int32)

In [485]: c1=sparse.csc_matrix((data[i],(cols[i],rows[i])),shape=(3,3))

In [486]: c1.A
Out[486]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 2],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

I have no idea which approach is faster.

---

An alternative way of getting the unique index, as per `liuengo's` link:

```
rc = np.vstack([rows,cols]).T.copy()
dt = rc.dtype.descr * 2
i = np.unique(rc.view(dt), return_index=True)[1]
```

`rc` has to own its own data in order to change the dtype with view, hence the `.T.copy()`.

```
In [554]: rc.view(dt)
Out[554]: 
array([[(0, 0)],
       [(1, 1)],
       [(2, 1)],
       [(1, 1)],
       [(1, 2)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Comment: Looks like a nice trick. I can't try it right now, does it take a lot of time/memory the conversion between types?

Comment: todok() doesn't ignoring duplicates at scipy 0.19

Comment: Yes, `coo.todok` now includes a `self.sum_duplicates()` line.  The solution is to do the update as I describe, but without this `sum`.

Comment: @hpaulj what solution? you mean using `todok()` function code without the line ` self.sum_duplicates()` ?

Comment: Seems like `i=np.unique(x,return_index=True)[1]` should be `i=np.unique(np.unique(x,return_index=True))` instead to yield the output of `[0, 1, 2, 4]`.

Answer (score 4):

Since the values in your `data` at repeating (row, col) are the same, you can get the unique rows, columns and values as follows:

```
rows, cols, data = zip(*set(zip(rows, cols, data)))
```

Example:

```
data = [4, 3, 4]
cols = [1, 2, 1]
rows = [1, 3, 1]

csc_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(4, 4)).todense()

matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 0]])



rows, cols, data = zip(*set(zip(rows, cols, data)))
csc_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(4, 4)).todense()

matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to update hpaulj's answer to the most recent version of SciPy, the simplest solution to this problem is now, given a COO matrix `c` now:

```
dok=sparse.dok_matrix((c.shape),dtype=c.dtype)
dok._update(zip(zip(c.row,c.col),c.data))

new_c = dok.tocsc()
```

This is due to a new wrapper in the dok `update()` function, preventing it from direct changes to the array, requiring the use of the underscore to bypass the wrapper.