# count occurrences of arrays in multidimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following type of arrays:

```
a = array([[1,1,1],
           [1,1,1],
           [1,1,1],
           [2,2,2],
           [2,2,2],
           [2,2,2],
           [3,3,0],
           [3,3,0],
           [3,3,0]])
```

I would like to count the number of occurrences of each type of array such as

```
[1,1,1]:3, [2,2,2]:3, and [3,3,0]: 3
```

How could I achieve this in python? Is it possible without using a for loop and counting into a dictionary?  It has to be fast and should take less than 0.1 seconds or so. I looked into Counter, numpy bincount, etc. But, those are for individual element not for an array.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find unique rows in numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind mapping to tuples just to get the count you can use a Counter dict which runs in  `28.5 µs` on my machine using python3 which is well below your threshold:

```
In [5]: timeit Counter(map(tuple, a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.5 µs per loop

In [6]: c = Counter(map(tuple, a))

In [7]: c
Out[7]: Counter({(2, 2, 2): 3, (1, 1, 1): 3, (3, 3, 0): 3})
```

Comment: No prob,  it is actually faster again in python2 just using map

Answer (score 2):

`collections.Counter` can do this conveniently, and almost like the [example given](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for x in a:
...   c[tuple(x)] += 1
...
>>> c
Counter({(2, 2, 2): 3, (1, 1, 1): 3, (3, 3, 0): 3})
```

This converts each sub-list to a tuple, which can be keys in a dictionary since they are immutable. Lists are mutable so can't be used as dict keys.

Why do you want to avoid using for loops?

And similar to [@padraic-cunningham's much cooler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235386/1431750):

```
>>> Counter(tuple(x) for x in a)
Counter({(2, 2, 2): 3, (1, 1, 1): 3, (3, 3, 0): 3})
>>> Counter(map(tuple, a))
Counter({(2, 2, 2): 3, (1, 1, 1): 3, (3, 3, 0): 3})
```

Comment: Python loops with numpy should be avoided as they can be many times slower than a numpy solution. Therefore, if you are using numpy and python loops you are likely "doing it wrong". In both the python answers you are copying the entire array to a much less compact datatype which is especially worrying.

Comment: @Ophion. do you have a faster numpy solution?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Divakar's solution will be faster for reasonably sized problems. This problem has been asked, answered, and benchmarked many times in the past. I think the canonical answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array).

Comment: @Ophion Re: "copying the entire array to a much less compact datatype". That's a good point. Though, I'd thought of taking it one further level of worrying by using a hash. But then also figured it to be unnecessarily complicated. One edit/addition I was going to put in the answer was retrieving the count of a certain elem, which is essentially a dict lookup in this case. So to print (for example) one of the counts, instead of `print c[(3, 3, 0)]`, one would put `print c.getcounts(3, 3, 0)` (or override `__getitem__` with the code for `getcounts`) and achieve a similar result.

Comment: Also, one has to decide how much they care about having the original items. On a "reasonably sized" array/list of large enough objects with not many repetitions, having one actual copy plus one in the Counter makes it unreasonable. So may be better to lose the value altogether and use a hash or str on the objects, for the dict keys. I was writing a generic `HashedCounter` but realised that by the time all the required methods involving keys are overridden as above, one would end up writing [most of this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/). But not Numpy-specific.

Comment: Added benchmark for a decently large input array case in my solution. That benchmarking trend continued for medium sized inputs as well. I think @Ophion made sense when he talked about NumPy solutions being optimized for such cases that goes with its philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert those rows to a 1D array using the elements as two-dimensional indices with [`np.ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html). Then, use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to give us the positions of the start of each unique row and also has an optional argument `return_counts` to give us the counts. Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
def unique_rows_counts(a):

    # Calculate linear indices using rows from a
    lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(a.T,a.max(0)+1 )

    # Get the unique indices and their counts
    _, unq_idx, counts = np.unique(lidx, return_index = True, return_counts=True)

    # return the unique groups from a and their respective counts
    return a[unq_idx], counts
```

Sample run -

```
In [64]: a
Out[64]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [3, 3, 0]])

In [65]: unqrows, counts = unique_rows_counts(a)

In [66]: unqrows
Out[66]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 0]])
In [67]: counts
Out[67]: array([3, 3, 3])
```

### Benchmarking

Assuming you are okay with either numpy arrays or collections as outputs, one can benchmark the solutions provided thus far, like so -

Function definitions:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def unique_rows_counts(a):
    lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(a.T,a.max(0)+1 )
    _, unq_idx, counts = np.unique(lidx, return_index = True, return_counts=True)
    return a[unq_idx], counts

def map_Counter(a):
    return Counter(map(tuple, a))    

def forloop_Counter(a):      
    c = Counter()
    for x in a:
        c[tuple(x)] += 1
    return c
```

Timings:

```
In [53]: a = np.random.randint(0,4,(10000,5))

In [54]: %timeit map_Counter(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.7 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit forloop_Counter(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 45.4 ms per loop

In [56]: %timeit unique_rows_counts(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop
```

Comment: Amazingly all the answers including the question got downvotes, makes one wonder!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I could add runtime tests, but then OP might be looking to have a dict as output, so that won't be fair :)

Comment: I will have to wait for the downvoter to release their superior solution so ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham /me is still waiting for this superior answer with bated breath ;-)

Comment: @aneroid Added some benchmarks if OP is okay with NumPy arrays as output. Hope that helps a bit on the breathing part ;)

Comment: +1 for numPythonic answer :-) And for the clarification. /aside: But I think we were waiting for whoever had downvoted all answers and the question :confused:

Comment: @aneroid Yours isn't bad either ;) Someone must had been really bored!

Comment: @Divakar Can you also time the `unique` example where its combined with `view`? I would be very curious to see the timings of `view` vs the multi index solution.

Comment: @Ophion I am not sure if I follow, view on what exactly?

Comment: @Divakar See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array), your `lidx` variable is not needed.

Comment: What about if the array contains negative numbers?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Then, I would think `a.max(0)` needs to be changed to `a.max(0) - a.min(0)`, though not tested.

Comment: @Divakarm so changing to min should work for positive and negative numbers?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I would think so, again as I said not tested, so not 100% sure, but the idea with `a.max(0)` was to give enough "separation" between consecutive tuples to be considered/simulate as indices of a multidimensional array. With the negative numbers, we just need to change that "separation" into more appropriate one by incorporating a.min(0).

Comment: I keep getting `ValueError: invalid entry in coordinates array`, the only way I could get it to work was to use `clip` instead of raise but not sure what implications that may have

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not tested for correctness, but something like - `base = a.min(0); 
lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(a.T- base.T[:,None],a.max(0)-base+1 )`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If you don't mind me asking - What's with the sudden interest in this old post? :)

Comment: @Divakar, a related question came up again and out of interest I was trying to compare creating a mapping of non unique elements to counts, it just would not work when there were negative numbers and it was beginning to drive me mad as to why

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah I see, well good to know it's still being used!

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains efficient vectorized functionality for these kind of operations:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_rows, row_count = npi.count(a, axis=0)
```

Note that this works for arrays of any dimensionality or datatype.

Comment: Perfect answer but how can we make it as one output: example [[[1,1,9],10],[[1,1,0],2]]

Comment: zip(*npi.count(..) would give that; but that wouldnt be very numpythonic; alternatively you could make a structured array with a composite dtype and assign the result to that, if you insist. But more likely that not you will end up wit ha more efficient solution if you stick to the way numpy likes to organise things natively.

Answer (score 1):

Since `numpy-1.13.0`, `np.unique` can be used with `axis` argument:

```
>>> np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=True)

(array([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 0]]), array([3, 3, 3]))
```