# Counting occurrences of columns in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2 x d dimensional numpy array M, I want to count the number of occurences of each column of M. That is, I'm looking for a general version of [`bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

What I tried so far: (1) Converted columns to tuples (2) Hashed tuples (via `hash`) to natural numbers (3) used `numpy.bincount`.

This seems rather clumsy. Is anybody aware of a more elegant and efficient way?

Comment: Interesting question. Looking forward to seeing any solutions because my first and only thought was exactly what you did.

Comment: So you are expecting a list of unique columns and their counts? Does the order of the columns have to be preserved?

Comment: Please show the code of your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  8,  9,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 12, 13,  9, 10, 11]])
b = np.transpose(a)
```

1. A more efficient solution than hashing (still requires manipulation):

   I create a view of the array with the flexible data type `np.void` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/1435522)) such that each row becomes a single element. Converting to this shape will allow `np.unique` to operate on it.

   ```
   %%timeit    
   c = np.ascontiguousarray(b).view(np.dtype((np.void, b.dtype.itemsize*b.shape[1])))
   _, index, counts = np.unique(c, return_index = True, return_counts = True)
   #counts are in the last column, remember original array is transposed
   >>>np.concatenate((b[idx], cnt[:, None]), axis = 1)
   array([[ 0,  4,  8,  1],
          [ 1,  5,  9,  2],
          [ 2,  6, 10,  2],
          [ 3,  7, 11,  1],
          [ 4,  8, 12,  1],
          [ 5,  9, 13,  1]])
   10000 loops, best of 3: 65.4 µs per loop
   ```

   The counts appended to the unique columns of `a`.
2. Your hashing solution.

   ```
   %%timeit
   array_hash = [hash(tuple(row)) for row in b]
   uniq, index, counts = np.unique(array_hash, return_index= True, return_counts = True)
   np.concatenate((b[idx], cnt[:, None]), axis = 1)
   10000 loops, best of 3: 89.5 µs per loop
   ```

**Update**: Eph's solution is the most efficient and elegant.

```
%%timeit
Counter(map(tuple, a.T))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  1,  2,  3],
...               [ 4,  5,  6,  8,  9,  5,  6,  7],
...               [ 8,  9, 10, 12, 13,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(map(tuple, a.T))
Counter({(2, 6, 10): 2, (1, 5, 9): 2, (4, 8, 12): 1, (5, 9, 13): 1, (3, 7, 11):
1, (0, 4, 8): 1})
```

Comment: how can I do the same if it was a 3d array. Basically I have a 3 channel image, so instead of each element in the above example I have 3 digits.