# Efficient way to check high dimensional arrays are overlapped in two ndarray in Python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, set-operations

For example, I have two ndarrays, the shape of `train_dataset` is `(10000, 28, 28)` and the shape of `val_dateset` is `(2000, 28, 28)`.

Except for using iterations, is there any efficient way to use the numpy array functions to find the overlap between two ndarrays?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "overlap"? Are you looking for the indices of rows that are found in both `train_dataset` and `val_dataset`?

Comment: Right, I want to find out the elements(28*28) that appear in both dataset.

Comment: If by any chance you're trying to _create_ training and validation datasets, you are much better off using scikit-learn's [cross_validation module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Answer (score 4):

One trick I learnt from [Jaime's excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/1461210) is to use an `np.void` dtype in order to view each row in the input arrays as a single element. This allows you to treat them as 1D arrays, which can then be passed to [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) or one of the other [set routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/routines.set.html).

```
import numpy as np

def find_overlap(A, B):

    if not A.dtype == B.dtype:
        raise TypeError("A and B must have the same dtype")
    if not A.shape[1:] == B.shape[1:]:
        raise ValueError("the shapes of A and B must be identical apart from "
                         "the row dimension")

    # reshape A and B to 2D arrays. force a copy if neccessary in order to
    # ensure that they are C-contiguous.
    A = np.ascontiguousarray(A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1))
    B = np.ascontiguousarray(B.reshape(B.shape[0], -1))

    # void type that views each row in A and B as a single item
    t = np.dtype((np.void, A.dtype.itemsize * A.shape[1]))

    # use in1d to find rows in A that are also in B
    return np.in1d(A.view(t), B.view(t))
```

For example:

```
gen = np.random.RandomState(0)

A = gen.randn(1000, 28, 28)
dupe_idx = gen.choice(A.shape[0], size=200, replace=False)
B = A[dupe_idx]

A_in_B = find_overlap(A, B)

print(np.all(np.where(A_in_B)[0] == np.sort(dupe_idx)))
# True
```

This method is much more memory-efficient than Divakar's, since it doesn't require broadcasting out to an `(m, n, ...)` boolean array. In fact, if `A` and `B` are row-major then no copying is required at all.

---

For comparison I've slightly adapted Divakar and B. M.'s solutions.

```
def divakar(A, B):
    A.shape = A.shape[0], -1
    B.shape = B.shape[0], -1
    return (B[:,None] == A).all(axis=(2)).any(0)

def bm(A, B):
    t = 'S' + str(A.size // A.shape[0] * A.dtype.itemsize)
    ma = np.frombuffer(np.ascontiguousarray(A), t)
    mb = np.frombuffer(np.ascontiguousarray(B), t)
    return (mb[:, None] == ma).any(0)
```

#### Benchmarks:

```
In [1]: na = 1000; nb = 200; rowshape = 28, 28

In [2]: %%timeit A = gen.randn(na, *rowshape); idx = gen.choice(na, size=nb, replace=False); B = A[idx]
divakar(A, B)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 244 ms per loop

In [3]: %%timeit A = gen.randn(na, *rowshape); idx = gen.choice(na, size=nb, replace=False); B = A[idx]
bm(A, B)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.81 ms per loop

In [4]: %%timeit A = gen.randn(na, *rowshape); idx = gen.choice(na, size=nb, replace=False); B = A[idx]
find_overlap(A, B)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop
```

As you can see, B. M.'s solution is slightly faster than mine for small *n*, but `np.in1d` scales better than testing equality for all elements (*O(n log n)* rather than *O(n²)* complexity).

```
In [5]: na = 10000; nb = 2000; rowshape = 28, 28

In [6]: %%timeit A = gen.randn(na, *rowshape); idx = gen.choice(na, size=nb, replace=False); B = A[idx]
bm(A, B)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 271 ms per loop

In [7]: %%timeit A = gen.randn(na, *rowshape); idx = gen.choice(na, size=nb, replace=False); B = A[idx]
find_overlap(A, B)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop
```

Divakar's solution is intractable on my laptop for arrays of this size, since it requires generating a 15GB intermediate array whereas I only have 8GB RAM.

Comment: Thanks this solution is really helpful.  I am trying to understand it a little better though.  What is the reason for using `np.ascontiguousarray(A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1))` instead of `np.array([x.flatten() for x in A])` which I have seen other code use to do something similar?  Is it a style thing, or do they do something different?

Comment: @Barker Try timing those two lines for a reasonably large input array. Firstly, the list comprehension will almost certainly be slower than a single call to `reshape`, especially if there are lots of rows in `A`. Also `.flatten()` always returns a copy (whereas `.reshape()` and `.ravel()` only return a copy if necessary), so you're making a temporary copy of each row in `A`, then another copy when you call `np.array(...)` on the list. `np.ascontiguousarray` only returns a copy if necessary, so my line creates at most a single copy of `A`.

Comment: This is the only solution (on this page) that works well for larger data sets. It should have more upvotes!

Answer (score 3):

Memory permitting you could use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
val_dateset[(train_dataset[:,None] == val_dateset).all(axis=(2,3)).any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [55]: train_dataset
Out[55]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 0]]])

In [56]: val_dateset
Out[56]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 1]]])

In [57]: val_dateset[(train_dataset[:,None] == val_dateset).all(axis=(2,3)).any(0)]
Out[57]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 1]]])
```

If the elements are integers, you could collapse every block of `axis=(1,2)` in the input arrays into a scalar assuming them as linearly index-able numbers and then efficiently use `np.in1d` or `np.intersect1d` to find the matches.

Answer (score 3):

Full broadcasting generate here a 10000*2000*28*28 =150 Mo boolean array.

For efficiency, you can :

- pack data, for a 200 ko array:

  ```
  from pylab import *
  N=10000
  a=rand(N,28,28)
  b=a[[randint(0,N,N//5)]]

  packedtype='S'+ str(a.size//a.shape[0]*a.dtype.itemsize) # 'S6272' 
  ma=frombuffer(a,packedtype)  # ma.shape=10000
  mb=frombuffer(b,packedtype)  # mb.shape=2000

  %timeit a[:,None]==b   : 102 s
  %timeit ma[:,None]==mb   : 800 ms
  allclose((a[:,None]==b).all((2,3)),(ma[:,None]==mb)) : True
  ```

  less memory is helped here by lazy string comparison, breaking at first difference :

  ```
  In [31]: %timeit a[:100]==b[:100]
  10000 loops, best of 3: 175 µs per loop

  In [32]: %timeit a[:100]==a[:100]
  10000 loops, best of 3: 133 µs per loop

  In [34]: %timeit ma[:100]==mb[:100]
  100000 loops, best of 3: 7.55 µs per loop

  In [35]: %timeit ma[:100]==ma[:100]
  10000 loops, best of 3: 156 µs per loop
  ```

Solutions are given here with `(ma[:,None]==mb).nonzero().`

- use `in1d`, for a `(Na+Nb) ln(Na+Nb)` complexity, against
  `Na*Nb` on full comparison :

  ```
  %timeit in1d(ma,mb).nonzero()  : 590ms
  ```

Not a big gain here, but asymptotically  better.

Comment: Great! Never knew short-circuiting could be achieved with strings like this. But maybe add a `ascontiguousarray` in there, so it works properly for arrays like `a = rand(28,28,N).T`.

Comment: @morningsun : you are right. In this case I just create the array, so it is contiguous, but for external data, `ma=frombuffer(ascontiguousarray(a),packedtype)` is safer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
def overlap(a,b):
    """
    returns a boolean index array for input array b representing
    elements in b that are also found in a
    """
    a.repeat(b.shape[0],axis=0)
    b.repeat(a.shape[0],axis=0)
    c = aa == bb
    c = c[::a.shape[0]]
    return c.all(axis=1)[:,0]
```

You can use the returned index array to index `b` to extract the elements which are also found in `a`

```
b[overlap(a,b)]
```

## Explanation

For simplicity's sake I assume you have imported everything from `numpy` for this example:

```
from numpy import *
```

So, for example, given two ndarrays

```
a = arange(4*2*2).reshape(4,2,2)
b = arange(3*2*2).reshape(3,2,2)
```

we repeat `a` and `b` so that they have the same shape

```
aa = a.repeat(b.shape[0],axis=0)
bb = b.repeat(a.shape[0],axis=0)
```

we can then simply compare the elements of `aa` and `bb`

```
c = aa == bb
```

Finally, to get the indices of the elements in `b` which are also found in `a` by looking at every 4th, or actually, every `shape(a)[0]`th element of `c`

```
cc == c[::a.shape[0]]
```

Finally, we extract an index array with only the elements where all elements in the sub-arrays are `True`

```
c.all(axis=1)[:,0]
```

In our example we get

```
array([True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

To check, change the first element of `b`

```
b[0] = array([[50,60],[70,80]])
```

and we get

```
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: The [solution by Divakar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34986744/1170207) is actually more clear and concise, +1.

Comment: I'd advise against polluting your namespace by doing `from numpy import *`

Answer (score 1):

This question comes form Google's online deep learning course?
The following is my solution:

```
sum = 0 # number of overlapping rows
for i in range(val_dataset.shape[0]): # iterate over all rows of val_dataset
    overlap = (train_dataset == val_dataset[i,:,:]).all(axis=1).all(axis=1).sum()
    if overlap:
        sum += 1
print(sum)
```

Automatic broadcasting is used instead of iteration. You may test the performance difference.