# Finding a set of indices that maps the rows of one NumPy ndarray to another

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, numpy, mapping

I have two structured 2D `numpy` arrays which are *equal* in principle, meaning

```
A = numpy.array([[a1,b1,c1],
                 [a2,b2,c2],
                 [a3,b3,c3],
                 [a4,b4,c4]]) 

B = numpy.array([[a2,b2,c2],
                 [a4,b4,c4],
                 [a3,b3,c3],
                 [a1,b1,c1]])
```

Not in the sense of

```
numpy.array_equal(A,B) # False
numpy.array_equiv(A,B) # False
numpy.equal(A,B) # ndarray of True and False
```

But in the sense that one array `(A)` is the *original* and in the other one `(B)` the data is shuffled along one axis (could be along the rows or columns).

What is an efficient way to sort/shuffle `B` to match or become equal to `A` or alternatively sort `A` to become equal to `B`? An equality check is indeed not important, as long as both arrays are shuffled to match each other. `A` and hence `B` have unique rows.

I tried the `view` method to sort both the arrays like so

```
def sort2d(A):
    A_view = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view(np.dtype((np.void,
             A.dtype.itemsize * A.shape[1])))
    A_view.sort()
    return A_view.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1,A.shape[1])
```

but that doesn't work here apparently. This operation needs to be performed for really large arrays, so performance and scalability is critical.

Comment: Is anything wrong with `B[:] = A`?

Comment: I cannot do that, as the rows of `A` and `B` are further mapped to array `C` and `D`, respectively, and the (row) order of `A` and `B` determines the values in `C` and `D`, so I cannot mess up the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example, it seems that you have shuffled all of the columns simultaneously, such that there is a vector of row indices that maps *A→B*. Here's a toy example:

```
A = np.random.permutation(12).reshape(4, 3)
idx = np.random.permutation(4)
B = A[idx]

print(repr(A))
# array([[ 7, 11,  6],
#        [ 4, 10,  8],
#        [ 9,  2,  0],
#        [ 1,  3,  5]])

print(repr(B))
# array([[ 1,  3,  5],
#        [ 4, 10,  8],
#        [ 7, 11,  6],
#        [ 9,  2,  0]])
```

We want to recover a set of indices, `idx`, such that `A[idx] == B`. This will be a unique mapping if and only if *A* and *B* contain no repeated rows.

---

One efficient* approach would be to find the indices that would lexically sort the rows in *A*, then find where each row in *B* would fall within the sorted version of *A*. [A useful trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array/16973510#16973510) is to view `A` and `B` as 1D arrays using an `np.void` dtype that treats each row as a single element:

```
rowtype = np.dtype((np.void, A.dtype.itemsize * A.size / A.shape[0]))
# A and B must be C-contiguous, might need to force a copy here
a = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view(rowtype).ravel()
b = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view(rowtype).ravel()

a_to_as = np.argsort(a)     # indices that sort the rows of A in lexical order
```

Now we can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to perform a binary search for where each row in *B* would fall within the sorted version of *A*:

```
# using the `sorter=` argument rather than `a[a_to_as]` avoids making a copy of `a`
as_to_b = a.searchsorted(b, sorter=a_to_as)
```

The mapping from *A→B* can be expressed as a composite of *A→A<sub>s</sub>→B*

```
a_to_b = a_to_as.take(as_to_b)
print(np.all(A[a_to_b] == B))
# True
```

If *A* and *B* contain no repeated rows, the inverse mapping from *B→A* can also be obtained using

```
b_to_a = np.argsort(a_to_b)
print(np.all(B[b_to_a] == A))
# True
```

#### As a single function:

```
def find_row_mapping(A, B):
    """
    Given A and B, where B is a copy of A permuted over the first dimension, find
    a set of indices idx such that A[idx] == B.
    This is a unique mapping if and only if there are no repeated rows in A and B.

    Arguments:
        A, B:   n-dimensional arrays with same shape and dtype
    Returns:
        idx:    vector of indices into the rows of A
    """

    if not (A.shape == B.shape):
        raise ValueError('A and B must have the same shape')
    if not (A.dtype == B.dtype):
        raise TypeError('A and B must have the same dtype')

    rowtype = np.dtype((np.void, A.dtype.itemsize * A.size / A.shape[0]))
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view(rowtype).ravel()
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view(rowtype).ravel()
    a_to_as = np.argsort(a)
    as_to_b = a.searchsorted(b, sorter=a_to_as)

    return a_to_as.take(as_to_b)
```

#### Benchmark:

```
In [1]: gen = np.random.RandomState(0)
In [2]: %%timeit A = gen.rand(1000000, 100); B = A.copy(); gen.shuffle(B)
....: find_row_mapping(A, B)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.76 s per loop
```

---

*The most costly step would be the quicksort over rows which is *O(n log n)* on average. I'm not sure it's possible to do any better than this.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, but are you sure this method works universally for any pair of arrays? Here is two consecutive runs of your code on my notebook: [one](http://cl.ly/0a3O3R1K1d2r), [two](http://cl.ly/3f3i1w1u381H). By the way I think you mean `idx` instead of `perm` on the second last line.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my forward vs inverse mappings. It should work now.

Comment: No worries. I tried an alternative using Jaime's answer by finding the unique rows of both arrays `vstack`ed together (posted below), although it does not seem as elegant of a solution as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Since either one of the arrays could be shuffled to match the other, no one has stopped us from re-arranging both. Using [Jaime's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array/16973510#16973510), we can `vstack` both the arrays and find the unique rows. Then the inverse indices returned by unique is essentially the desired mapping (as the arrays don't contain duplicate rows).

Let's first define a `unique2d` function for convenience:

```
def unique2d(arr,consider_sort=False,return_index=False,return_inverse=False): 
    """Get unique values along an axis for 2D arrays.

        input:
            arr:
                2D array
            consider_sort:
                Does permutation of the values within the axis matter? 
                Two rows can contain the same values but with 
                different arrangements. If consider_sort 
                is True then those rows would be considered equal
            return_index:
                Similar to numpy unique
            return_inverse:
                Similar to numpy unique
        returns:
            2D array of unique rows
            If return_index is True also returns indices
            If return_inverse is True also returns the inverse array 
            """

    if consider_sort is True:
        a = np.sort(arr,axis=1)
    else:
        a = arr
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, 
            a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))

    if return_inverse is False:
        _, idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
    else:
        _, idx, inv = np.unique(b, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

    if return_index == False and return_inverse == False:
        return arr[idx]
    elif return_index == True and return_inverse == False:
        return arr[idx], idx
    elif return_index == False and return_inverse == True:
        return arr[idx], inv
    else:
        return arr[idx], idx, inv
```

We can now define our mapping as follows

```
def row_mapper(a,b,consider_sort=False):
    """Given two 2D numpy arrays returns mappers idx_a and idx_b 
        such that a[idx_a] = b[idx_b] """

    assert a.dtype == b.dtype
    assert a.shape == b.shape

    c = np.concatenate((a,b))
    _, inv = unique2d(c, consider_sort=consider_sort, return_inverse=True)
    mapper_a = inv[:b.shape[0]]
    mapper_b = inv[b.shape[0]:]

    return np.argsort(mapper_a), np.argsort(mapper_b)
```

**Verify**:

```
n = 100000
A = np.arange(n).reshape(n//4,4)
B = A[::-1,:]

idx_a, idx_b  = row_mapper(A,B)
print np.all(A[idx_a]==B[idx_b])
# True
```

**Benchmark**:
benchmark against @ali_m's solution

```
%timeit find_row_mapping(A,B) # ali_m's solution
%timeit row_mapper(A,B) # current solution

# n = 100
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.3 µs per loop

# n = 1000
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.1 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 148 µs per loop

# n = 10000
1000 loops, best of 3: 548 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop

# n = 100000
100 loops, best of 3: 6.96 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 19.3 ms per loop

# n = 1000000
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 372 ms per loop

# n = 10000000
1 loops, best of 3: 2.54 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 5.92 s per loop
```

Although maybe there is room for improvement, the current solution is 2-3 times slower than ali_m's solution and perhaps a little messier as well as both arrays need to be mapped. Just thought this could be an alternate solution.

Comment: `np.unique` [uses `argsort` internally](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L194-L196). The performance difference probably comes down to the fact that you are sorting both of the arrays rather than just one, plus some extra copying of the inputs.