# Check common elements of two 2D numpy arrays, either row or column wise

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Given two `numpy` arrays of `nx3` and `mx3`, what is an efficient way to determine the row indices (counter) wherein the rows are common in the two arrays. For instance I have the following solution, which is significantly slow for not even much larger arrays

```
def arrangment(arr1,arr2):
    hits = []
    for i in range(arr2.shape[0]):
        current_row = np.repeat(arr2[i,:][None,:],arr1.shape[0],axis=0)
        x = current_row - arr1
        for j in range(arr1.shape[0]):
            if np.isclose(x[j,0],0.0) and np.isclose(x[j,1],0.0) and np.isclose(x[j,2],0.0):
                hits.append(j)

    return hits
```

It checks if rows of `arr2` exist in `arr1` and returns the row indices of `arr1` where the rows match. I need this arrangement to be always sequentially ascending in terms of rows of `arr2`. For instance given

```
arr1 = np.array([[-1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1., -1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.]])
arr2 = np.array([[-1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The function should return:

```
[3, 2, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 3):

quick and dirty answer

```
(arr1[:, None] == arr2).all(-1).argmax(0)

array([3, 2, 6, 7])
```

---

Better answer
Takes care of chance a row in `arr2` doesn't match anything in `arr1`

```
t = (arr1[:, None] == arr2).all(-1)
np.where(t.any(0), t.argmax(0), np.nan)

array([ 3.,  2.,  6.,  7.])
```

---

As pointed out by @Divakar `np.isclose` accounts for rounding error in comparing floats

```
t = np.isclose(arr1[:, None], arr2).all(-1)
np.where(t.any(0), t.argmax(0), np.nan)
```

Comment: Use `np.isclose(arr1[:, None],arr2)` to account for floating pt numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar [problem in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234571/finding-a-set-of-indices-that-maps-the-rows-of-one-numpy-ndarray-to-another) and I came up with a fairly optimised solution for it.

First you need a generalisation of `numpy.unique` for multidimensional arrays, which for the sake of completeness I would [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35242447/2750396) it here

```
def unique2d(arr,consider_sort=False,return_index=False,return_inverse=False): 
    """Get unique values along an axis for 2D arrays.

        input:
            arr:
                2D array
            consider_sort:
                Does permutation of the values within the axis matter? 
                Two rows can contain the same values but with 
                different arrangements. If consider_sort 
                is True then those rows would be considered equal
            return_index:
                Similar to numpy unique
            return_inverse:
                Similar to numpy unique
        returns:
            2D array of unique rows
            If return_index is True also returns indices
            If return_inverse is True also returns the inverse array 
            """

    if consider_sort is True:
        a = np.sort(arr,axis=1)
    else:
        a = arr
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, 
            a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))

    if return_inverse is False:
        _, idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
    else:
        _, idx, inv = np.unique(b, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

    if return_index == False and return_inverse == False:
        return arr[idx]
    elif return_index == True and return_inverse == False:
        return arr[idx], idx
    elif return_index == False and return_inverse == True:
        return arr[idx], inv
    else:
        return arr[idx], idx, inv
```

Now all you need is to concatenate (`np.vstack`) your arrays and find the unique rows. The reverse mapping together with `np.searchsorted` will give you the indices you need. So lets write another function similar to `numpy.in2d` but for multidimensional (2D) arrays

```
def in2d_unsorted(arr1, arr2, axis=1, consider_sort=False):
    """Find the elements in arr1 which are also in 
       arr2 and sort them as the appear in arr2"""

    assert arr1.dtype == arr2.dtype

    if axis == 0:
        arr1 = np.copy(arr1.T,order='C')
        arr2 = np.copy(arr2.T,order='C')

    if consider_sort is True:
        sorter_arr1 = np.argsort(arr1)
        arr1 = arr1[np.arange(arr1.shape[0])[:,None],sorter_arr1]
        sorter_arr2 = np.argsort(arr2)
        arr2 = arr2[np.arange(arr2.shape[0])[:,None],sorter_arr2]


    arr = np.vstack((arr1,arr2))
    _, inv = unique2d(arr, return_inverse=True)

    size1 = arr1.shape[0]
    size2 = arr2.shape[0]

    arr3 = inv[:size1]
    arr4 = inv[-size2:]

    # Sort the indices as they appear in arr2
    sorter = np.argsort(arr3)
    idx = sorter[arr3.searchsorted(arr4, sorter=sorter)]

    return idx
```

Now all you need to do is call `in2d_unsorted` with your input parameters

```
>>> in2d_unsorted(arr1,arr2)
array([ 3,  2,  6,  7])
```

While may not be fully optimised this approach is much faster. Let's benchmark it against `@piRSquared`s solutions

```
def indices_piR(arr1,arr2):
    t = np.isclose(arr1[:, None], arr2).all(-1)
    return np.where(t.any(0), t.argmax(0), np.nan)
```

with the following arrays

```
n=150
arr1 = np.random.permutation(n).reshape(n//3, 3)
idx = np.random.permutation(n//3)
arr2 = arr1[idx]

In [13]: np.allclose(in2d_unsorted(arr1,arr2),indices_piR(arr1,arr2))
True

In [14]: %timeit indices_piR(arr1,arr2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 181 µs per loop
In [15]: %timeit in2d_unsorted(arr1,arr2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.7 µs per loop
```

Now, for `n=1500`

```
In [24]: %timeit indices_piR(arr1,arr2)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop
In [25]: %timeit in2d_unsorted(arr1,arr2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 403 µs per loop
```

and for `n=15000`

```
In [28]: %timeit indices_piR(A,B)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop
In [29]: %timeit in2d_unsorted(arr1,arr2)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.65 ms per loop
```

So for large`ish` arrays this is over **200X** faster compared to `@piRSquared`'s vectorised solution.