# Numpy: How to find the arguments of 2D array inside another 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Before posting this question, I have searched to find a solution on this website but cannot find any solution.

Suppose that I have 2 numpy 2D arrays, `a` and `b`, such that:

```py
a = np.array([[0. , 1.],
              [0.5, 1.6],
              [1.2, 3.2],
              [4. , 3. ],
              [4.7, 3.5],
              [5.9, 2.4],
              [7.6, 8.8],
              [9.5, 6.2]
              ])

b = np.array([[7.6, 8.8],
              [4. , 3. ],
              [9.5, 6.2],
              [1.2, 3.2]
              ])
```

I want to get the arguments of the array `b` in the array `a`. That is, for each row of `b` return its location on `b`.
In this case, the expected result is something like:

```
args =np.array([6, 3, 7, 2])
```

I've tried with something like:

```
args = np.argwhere(a == b) # But the result is an empty array
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
temp_search = (a[:, None] == b).all(-1)
args = np.where(temp_search.any(0), temp_search.argmax(0), np.nan)
args = args[~np.isnan(args)].astype(int)
```

Outputs:

```
[6 3 7 2]
```

---

The issue seems to be in `a==b`. Instead of returning an `np array` it's returning just a boolean value i.e. `false`.

Seems like `elementwise`  comparison using `==` between 2 numpy arrays is deprecated for a while now.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6784

Reference: [Check common elements of two 2D numpy arrays, either row or column wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234161/check-common-elements-of-two-2d-numpy-arrays-either-row-or-column-wise)

---

This is an enhanced version that handles duplicates in arrays, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58735246/10957988) for reference.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def assign_duplbl(a):
    df = pd.DataFrame(a)
    df['num'] = 1
    return df.groupby(list(range(a.shape[1]))).cumsum().values

def argwhere2d(arr, target_arr):
    # return the location of arr in the target_array

    # this is an updated version to handle duplicates
    a = np.hstack((arr,assign_duplbl(arr)))
    b = np.hstack((target_arr,assign_duplbl(target_arr)))
    temp_search = (b[:, None] == a).all(-1)
    args = np.where(temp_search.any(0), temp_search.argmax(0), np.nan)
    args = args[~np.isnan(args)].astype(int) 
    return args
```

Comment: I got `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0`

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician, are both your array's a and b 2d like you mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes of course they are both 2d. `a.shape is (8,2)` and `b.shape is (4,2)`

Comment: I got an empty array. Please try to execute your instructions

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Again, an empty array. Could you please run your answer?

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician,  The issue seems to be in `a==b`. Instead of returning an np array it's returning just a boolean value i.e. `false`. Seems like `elementwise` comparission betwen numpy array is deprecated with '=='. We need to find an alternative for this.

Comment: I've solved it.

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician, I've updated the answer to a solution, that should work now :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, Actually your answer is about 16x faster then mine. Could you just explain your code?

Comment: There is something wrong with this. If an element in `b` doesn't exist in `a` then it returns `0` for argument.

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician, updated the answer so it takes care of missing elements scenario.

Comment: This return float dtype array. it should be integers. Also the nan values should be removed from the result with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620914/removing-nan-values-from-an-array

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician, you can do `args.astype(int)` to convert floats to int. And you can then remove nan values from the result like in the link you've shown.