# How to take set complement of numpy.ndarrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays of images,

```
X.shape =(76,224,224,3)
X_1.shape =(15,224,224,3)
```

The 15 images in X_1 are also in X. How can I get Z = X \ X_1? where Z may have shape=(61,224,224,3).

Thanks to all.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by intersection here? Full context match?

Comment: I mean that X_1 is contained in X, so i want to get the rest images that are in X and not in X_1.

Answer (score 1):

> The 15 images in X_1 are in X.

Doesn't that mean `X∩X_1=X_1` since entire `X_1` contained in `X`, so you just want `Z = X-X_1`?

I think you should look into [numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)

---

This is probably (definitely) not the fastest or the best way, but I got it to work by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234161/check-common-elements-of-two-2d-numpy-arrays-either-row-or-column-wise),

```py
>>> X = np.random.randint(255, size=(76,224,224,3))
>>> X_1 = X[:15]
>>> X.shape
(76, 224, 224, 3)
>>> X_1.shape
(15, 224, 224, 3)
>>> ind_to_del = np.unique((X[:, None] == X_1).all(-1).argmax(0))
>>> ind_to_del
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>> Z = np.delete(X, ind_to_del, axis=0)
>>> Z.shape
(61, 224, 224, 3)
```

So you want,

```py
ind_to_del = np.unique((X[:, None] == X_1).all(-1).argmax(0))
Z = np.delete(X, ind_to_del, axis=0)
```

Comment: This isn't what I want. Yes, I want to do X-X_1 but when I do it throws this error. operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (76,224,224,3) (15,224,224,3)

Comment: What is X \ X_1?  Its the same as X / X_1?

Comment: Okay i got you, You mean the compliment. With numpy i cant do it with both sets because: this is the method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html 
and only accept 1d arrays.