# Position of indices of a list with respect to another list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to locate the positions of indices of list `B`: `(0,2),(2,1)` with respect to list `A`. But there is an error. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy 
A=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
B=[(0,2),(2,1)]
C=B.index(A)
print("C =",C)
```

The error is

```
<module>
    C=B.index(A)

ValueError: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)] is not in list
```

The desired output is

```
[3,8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the indices of the wanted pairs, you can do:

```
a=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
b=[(0,2),(2,1)]
c=[a.index(b_item) for b_item in b]
print("C =", c)
```

This will print [2,7] (indices starting from 0).
Alternatively, if you want indices starting from 1 as output (result [3,8]):

```
a=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
b=[(0,2),(2,1)]
c=[a.index(b_item)+1 for b_item in b]
print("C =", c)
```

Note that this will result in an error if the pair is not in list a. You can work with `try` and `except ValueError` if you want to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do can be solved with a list comprehension as follows:

```
import numpy 
A=[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
B=[(0,2),(2,1)]
C= [A.index(element) for element in B]
print("C =",C)
```

That will return:

```
[2,7]
```

If you want it to return your desired output, just do:

```
C= [A.index(element)+1 for element in B]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you tag [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy). You need to check each row of `B` with each row in `A` then use `numpy.all` and `numpy.any`. *(but you need to consider in python, Index start from zero, if you want [3,8]. you need to `+1` result.)*

```
>>> np.argwhere((A==B[:,None]).all(-1).any(0)).ravel()
array([2, 7])
```

Explanation:

```
>>> A = np.asarray(A)
>>> B = np.asarray(B)
>>> A == B[:,None]
array([[[ True, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True, False]]])

>>> (A==B[:,None]).all(axis=-1)
array([[False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False]])

>>> (A==B[:,None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0) <- you want index of this array that have `True` value
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False])

>>> np.argwhere((A==B[:,None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0))
array([[2],
       [7]])

>>> np.argwhere((A==B[:,None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0)).ravel()
array([2, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` have no duplicates and `B`s are contained in the `A`, you can do this [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41234399/13394817):

```
(np.array(A)[:, None] == np.array(B)).all(-1).argmax(0) + 1
# [3, 8]
```

I have used `+1` because indexing in Numpy arrays are starting from `0`. I recommend using numpy equivalent methods instead of loops because they will be much better than loops in terms of performance when working on large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Olli's answer is obviously correct, but I feel there are a few misundertandings in your post that need an explanation.

`C=B.index(A)` asks for the position of `A` in `B`, which I believe is quite the opposite of what you want. Hence the error, `A` is not in `B`. But even `A.index(B)` would give an error, because once more `B` as a whole is not in `A`.

What you want to know is the position in `A` of each single element of `B`, or to be more precise of the first occurence in `A` of each element of `B`. So you need to iterate over each element of `B` and find its position in `A`. This can be done in a few different ways, but the logic will always be the same