# Scikit-learn multiple targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, multilabel-classification

I left this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) to create a classifier images with scikit-learn.

Though each image belongs to a single category everything works, but each image may belong to several categories, such as: photos with daytime dogs, pictures of cats at night, pictures of cats and dogs at night etc ...
I wrote:

```
target=[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[0,2,3]]
target = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(target)

classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
classifier.fit(data, target)
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 49, in <module>
    classifier.fit(data, target)
  File "/home/mezzo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 151, in fit
    y = self._validate_targets(y)
  File "/home/mezzo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 514, in _validate_targets
    y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/home/mezzo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 551, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (4, 4)
```

Complete code

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# The digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

def normalize(old_im):
    base = 400

    if (old_im.size[0] > old_im.size[1]):
        wpercent = (base/float(old_im.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(old_im.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        old_im = old_im.resize((base,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    else:
        wpercent = (base/float(old_im.size[1]))
        wsize = int((float(old_im.size[0])*float(wpercent)))
        old_im = old_im.resize((wsize, base), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

    old_size = old_im.size

    new_size = (base, base)
    new_im = Image.new("RGB", new_size)
    new_im.paste(old_im, ((new_size[0]-old_size[0])/2,
                          (new_size[1]-old_size[1])/2))

    #new_im.show()
    new_im.save('prov.jpg')
    return mpimg.imread('prov.jpg')

# To apply a classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
imgs = np.array([normalize(Image.open('/home/mezzo/Immagini/1.jpg')),normalize(Image.open('/home/mezzo/Immagini/2.jpg')),normalize(Image.open('/home/mezzo/Immagini/3.jpg')),normalize(Image.open('/home/mezzo/Immagini/4.jpg'))])
n_samples = len(imgs)
data = imgs.reshape((n_samples, -1))

target=[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[0,2,3]]
target = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(target)

# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(data, target)

# Now predict the value of the digit on the second half:
predicted = classifier.predict(data)

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(target, predicted)))
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(target, predicted))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit-learn's SVM implementation doesn't natively support multilabel classification, [although it has various other classifiers that do](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html):

> - Support multilabel: [Decision Trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree), [Random Forests](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest), [Nearest Neighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#neighbors), [Ridge Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression).

---

It's also possible to do multilabel classification with SVM by treating each unique combination of labels as a separate class. You could simply replace each unique row in your `target` matrix with a single integer label, [which can be done efficiently using `np.unique`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/1461210):

```
d = np.dtype((np.void, target.dtype.itemsize * target.shape[1]))
_, ulabels = np.unique(np.ascontiguousarray(target).view(d), return_inverse=True)
```

Then you could train SVM as you would for a single-label classification problem:

```
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(data, ulabels)
```

One potential caveat is that your classifier's performance may be poor for rare combinations of labels if you don't have a large number of training examples.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I get this error with the code that you passed me.: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: thank for the answer, now i see: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: create a file .py with this line, you can replicate the error:
target=[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[0,2,3]]
target = np.array(target)
d = np.dtype((np.void, target.dtype.itemsize * target.shape[1]))
_, ulabels = np.unique(np.ascontiguousarray(target).view(d), return_inverse=True)

Comment: You need `target` to be your binary multilabel representation, i.e.: `target = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform([[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[0,2,3]])`. If you try to convert your nested lists directly to an array you will get an `np.object` array, since the row lengths are unequal.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your target is :

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Your target must be of shape (m,), where m is number of examples.
One way to deal with that is to convert your binary arrays to labels, like that:

```
for item in target:
    print(sum(1<<i for i, b in enumerate(item) if b))
```

The output of this will be :

```
3
5
6
13
```

Now you can use `[3,5,6,13]` as your targets.

Comment: you create a new label for every subset of possible categories, just like in example.