# Is there Python equivalent to MATLAB unique?

Tags: python, matlab

I am rewriting one code

```
nd = unique(nd,'rows');
```

Documentation from The Mathworks

> `C = unique(A,'rows')` treats each row of `A` as a single entity and returns the unique rows of `A`. The rows of the array `C` are in sorted order.

Is there something like this in Python or I have to use sort?

Comment: if nd is a list of tuples you can just use `sorted(set(nd))` I guess ... if its lists then that will break since lists are mutable they cannot be hashed...

Comment: Also `np.unique` from numpy.

Comment: lol np.unique is probably the right answer :P I figured np had something

Comment: I second that. If you're migrating MATLAB code, you should be using numpy anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# Having an array:
a = [1,2,2,3,4,4,3]
print ("Original vector:")
print(a)

# Printting unique values of a:
print ("Unique values of a:")
print (np.unique(a))

# Other option:
print  ("Another way:")
print (set(a))
```

Ouput:

```
Original vector:
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3]
Unique values of a:
[1 2 3 4]
Another way:
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: The MATLAB `unique` with 'rows' specified finds the unique *rows*.  `np.unique` will return the unique elements from the flattened array.  For 2D arrays see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

**Python:**

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 5],[1, 0, 0],[2,2,5],[2,3,5]])
c, ia, ic= np.unique(a,return_index=True,return_inverse=True, axis=0)
```

This will give the same result as the `unique` function of Matlab. The only difference is the base index which starts from 0 in Python.