# Detect the first unique rows in multiple numpy 2-d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have multiple numpy 2-d arrays which I want to compare rowwise. The output of my function should be a numpy 2-d array representing all rows of the three inputs arrays. I want to be able to detect the first time that a row occurs, every second or third duplicate row should be flagged as False in the output. It is not possible to have duplicate rows within a single array.

If it is possible I would like to avoid the use of loops, as they slow down the calculation speed.

Example:

```
array1 = array([[444, 427],
   [444, 428],
   [444, 429],
   [444, 430],
   [445, 421]], dtype=uint64)

array2 = array([[446, 427],
   [446, 440],
   [444, 429],
   [444, 432],
   [445, 421]], dtype=uint64)

array3 = array([[447, 427],
   [446, 441],
   [444, 429],
   [444, 432],
   [445, 421]], dtype=uint64)

# output
array([[True, True, True, True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  False, True,  False],
   [ True,  True,  False, False,  False]], dtype=bool)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you care about duplicate rows within the same array?

Comment: Good one. It is not possible to have duplicate rows within the same array (Will add that to the question).

Comment: What if the last row of `array3` were `[444, 427]` instead, what must be the output's last row, last column element be?

Comment: as divakar says, it is not clear in your question if you want a hstack or a vstack

Comment: @Divakar it must be false

Comment: I see. So, you were looking for global duplicates then. Good to know!

Comment: @B.M. vstack I suppose, the answer of ali_m yields the expected results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fast vectorized approach:

```
def find_dupe_rows(*arrays):

    A = np.vstack(arrays)
    rtype = np.dtype((np.void, A.dtype.itemsize*A.shape[1]))
    _, first_idx = np.unique(A.view(rtype), return_index=True)
    out = np.zeros(A.shape[0], np.bool)
    out[first_idx] = True

    return out.reshape(len(arrays), -1)
```

Example usage:

```
print(find_dupe_rows(array1, array2, array3))
# [[ True  True  True  True  True]
#  [ True  True False  True False]
#  [ True  True False False False]]
```

---

To break that down a bit:

1. Stack the three subarrays to produce a `(15, 2)` array:

   ```
   A = np.vstack((array1, array2, array3))
   ```
2. Use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) together with [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/1461210) to efficiently find the indices where each unique row first occurs within `A`:

   ```
   rtype = np.dtype((np.void, A.dtype.itemsize * A.shape[1]))
   _, first_idx = np.unique(A.view(rtype), return_index=True)
   ```
3. Every row that isn't the first occurrence of a unique row can be treated as a duplicate:

   ```
   out = np.zeros(A.shape[0], np.bool)     # output is False by default
   out[first_idx] = True                   # set first occurrences to True
   ```
4. Finally, reshape this boolean vector to `(narrays, nrows)`, as per your example output:

   ```
   return out.reshape(len(arrays), -1)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfect, I will implement it in my script today.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for duplicates along the same row IDs across the `2D` input arrays, here's a vectorized approach -

```
# Concatenate all input 2D arrays to form a single tall 2D array
A = np.vstack((array1,array2,array3))

# Consider the rows of the 2D input arrays as linear indexing tuples. 
# Thus, we can reduce the input size, reduced by length of rows.
# This would help in simplifying the solution ahead and help in performance.
A_lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(A.T,A.max(0)+1).reshape(-1,array1.shape[0])

# Finally use broadcasting to perform elementwise comparison between 
# the elements of each column against themselves. Then, use argmax 
# along the first axis giving us the first indices of the duplicates, 
# which when compared with index ID would lead us to final boolean array.
out = (A_lidx[:,None] == A_lidx).argmax(0) == np.arange(A_lidx.shape[0])[:,None]
```

If you were looking for a global search across all rows of all `2D` input arrays, you need a bit modified approach, like so -

```
# Concatenate all input 2D arrays to form a single tall 2D array
A = np.vstack((array1,array2,array3))

# Consider the rows of the 2D input arrays as linear indexing tuples. 
# Thus, we can reduce the input size, reduced by length of rows.
# This would help in simplifying the solution ahead and help in performance.
A_lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(A.T,A.max(0)+1).ravel()

# Find first occurances by differentiating sorted version and 
# looking for indices with positive change.
sidx = A_lidx.argsort()
first_occ = sidx[np.append(0,np.where(np.diff(A_lidx[sidx])>0)[0]+1)]

# Finally, set those indices as True in an output array of appropriate length
out = np.in1d(np.arange(len(A_lidx)),first_occ).reshape(3,-1)
```

Please note that the step to calculate `first_occ` is basically a crude way of using `np.unique(..., return_index=True)` as used in [`@ali_m's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37104973/3293881).

Answer (score 3):

```
array1 = np.array([[444, 427],
   [444, 428],
   [444, 429],
   [444, 430],
   [445, 421]])

array2 = np.array([[446, 427],
   [446, 440],
   [444, 429],
   [444, 432],
   [445, 421]])

array3 = np.array([[447, 427],
   [446, 441],
   [444, 429],
   [444, 432],
   [445, 421]])

array_list = [array1,array2,array3]
x = set()
check = np.ones((len(array_list),array1.shape[0]),dtype=bool)
for i,item in enumerate(array_list):
    for j in range(item.shape[0]):
        temp = tuple(item[j,:])
        if temp in x:
            check[i,j] = False
        else:
            x.add(temp)

print check
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Awesome, the output is indeed correct! However, solution without loops would  be more optimal, therefore I will not yet mark this question as solved. Still, thanks a lot!