# Find unique pairs in list of pairs

Tags: python, list

I have a (large) list of lists of integers, e.g.,

```
a = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 6],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 5],
    [3, 6]
    ]
```

Most of the pairs will appear twice, where the order of the integers doesn't matter (i.e., `[1, 2]` is equivalent to `[2, 1]`). I'd now like to find the pairs that appear only *once*, and get a Boolean list indicating that. For the above example,

```
b = [False, False, False, True, False]
```

Since `a` is typically large, I'd like to avoid explicit loops. Mapping to `frozenset`s may be advised, but I'm not sure if that's overkill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a solution with NumPy that 10 times faster than the suggested `frozenset` solution:

```py
a = numpy.array(a)
a.sort(axis=1)
b = numpy.ascontiguousarray(a).view(
    numpy.dtype((numpy.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
)
_, inv, ct = numpy.unique(b, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
print(ct[inv] == 1)
```

- Sorting is fast and makes sure that the edges `[i, j]`, `[j, i]` in the original array identify with each other. Much faster than `frozenset`s or `tuple`s.
- Row uniquification inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/353337.

Speed comparison for different array sizes:

[image]

The plot was created with

```py
from collections import Counter
import numpy
import perfplot


def fs(a):
    ctr = Counter(frozenset(x) for x in a)
    b = [ctr[frozenset(x)] == 1 for x in a]
    return b


def with_numpy(a):
    a = numpy.array(a)
    a.sort(axis=1)
    b = numpy.ascontiguousarray(a).view(
        numpy.dtype((numpy.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    )
    _, inv, ct = numpy.unique(b, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    res = ct[inv] == 1
    return res


perfplot.save(
    "out.png",
    setup=lambda n: numpy.random.randint(0, 10, size=(n, 2)),
    kernels=[fs, with_numpy],
    labels=["frozenset", "numpy"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(15)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
ctr = Counter(frozenset(x) for x in a)
b = [ctr[frozenset(x)] == 1 for x in a]
```

We can use Counter to get counts of each list (turn list to frozenset to ignore order) and then for each list check if it only appears once.

Comment: While this is pretty clean, this will return `b = [True, False, False, True, False]`, which is different from example output.

Comment: Instead of `tuple(sorted(x))` you could also use `frozenset(x)`

Comment: `frozenset` performs a bit better than the sorted tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @tobias_k, fixed.

Comment: About twice as fast: `ctr = Counter(map(frozenset, a)); b = numpy.array(ctr.values()) == 1`. You may want to adapt your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could scan the list from start to end, while maintaining a `map` of encountered pairs to their first position. Whenever you process a pair, you check to see if you've encountered it before. If that's the case, both the first encounter's index in b and the current encounter's index must be set to False. Otherwise, we just add the current index to the map of encountered pairs and change nothing about b. b will start initially all `True`. To keep things equivalent wrt `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`, I'd first simply sort the pair, to obtain a stable representation. The code would look something like this:

```
def proc(a):
  b = [True] * len(a) # Better way to allocate this
  filter = {}
  idx = 0
  for p in a:
    m = min(p)
    M = max(p)
    pp = (m, M)
    if pp in filter:
      # We've found the element once previously
      # Need to mark both it and the current value as "False"
      # If we encounter pp multiple times, we'll set the initial
      # value to False multiple times, but that's not an issue
      b[filter[pp]] = False
      b[idx] = False
    else:
      # This is the first time we encounter pp, so we just add it
      # to the filter for possible later encounters, but don't affect
      # b at all.
      filter[pp] = idx
    idx++
  return b
```

The time complexity is `O(len(a))` which is good, but the space complexity is also `O(len(a))` (for `filter`), so this might not be so great. Depending on how flexible you are, you can use an approximate filter such as a Bloom filter.

Answer (score 2):

```
#-*- coding : utf-8 -*-
a = [[1, 2], [3, 6], [2, 1], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
result = filter(lambda el:(a.count([el[0],el[1]]) + a.count([el[1],el[0]]) == 1),a)
bool_res = [ (a.count([el[0],el[1]]) + a.count([el[1],el[0]]) == 1) for el in a]
print result
print bool_res
```

wich gives :

```
[[3, 5]]
[False, False, False, True, False]
```

Comment: If `a = [[1, 1]]`, `bool_res` should be `[True]` but your approach yields `[False]`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary for an O(n) solution.

```
a = [ [1, 2], [3, 6], [2, 1], [3, 5], [3, 6] ]

dict = {}
boolList = []

# Iterate through a
for i in range (len(a)):

    # Assume that this element is not a duplicate
    # This 'True' is added to the corresponding index i of boolList
    boolList += [True]

    # Set elem to the current pair in the list
    elem = a[i]

    # If elem is in ascending order, it will be entered into the map as is
    if elem[0] <= elem[1]:
        key = repr(elem)
    # If not, change it into ascending order so keys can easily be compared
    else:
        key = repr( [ elem[1] ] + [ elem[0] ])

    # If this pair has not yet been seen, add it as a key to the dictionary
    # with the value a list containing its index in a.
    if key not in dict:
        dict[key] = [i]
    # If this pair is a duploicate, add the new index to the dict. The value
    # of the key will contain a list containing the indeces of that pair in a.
    else:
        # Change the value to contain the new index
        dict[key] += [i]

        # Change boolList for this to True for this index
        boolList[i] = False

        # If this is the first duplicate for the pair, make the first
        # occurrence of the pair into a duplicate as well.
        if len(dict[key]) <= 2:
            boolList[ dict[key][0] ] = False

print a
print boolList
```