# 2D equivalent of numpy.unique

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of discretized coordinates in a Nx2 `numpy.ndarray`.

I would like to get the counts and indices of each of these unique coordinate sets. [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) does exactly this, but for scalar elements.

Is there some clean way to do this using `numpy`?

Example:

```
#input
coor = np.array([[10,10],[12,9],[10,5],[12,9]]) 
#output
unique_count = np.array([1,2,1])
unique_index = np.array([0,1,2]) #1 could also be 3
```

EDIT:
`unique count`, would give the counts of each of the unique values, ie: 1 of `[10,10]`, 2 of `[12,9]` and 1 of `[10,5]`. One would then find the values these correspond to with `coor[unique_index]`

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the content of unique_count and unique_index? I don't understand it.

Comment: @Ohumeronen Because I want the indices of the coordinate pairs, not the count if each of the X/Y- coordinates themselves

Comment: I begin to understand...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.count()` and `.index()` list's methods

```
coor = np.array([[10, 10], [12, 9], [10, 5], [12, 9]])
coor_tuple = [tuple(x) for x in coor]
unique_coor = sorted(set(coor_tuple), key=lambda x: coor_tuple.index(x))
unique_count = [coor_tuple.count(x) for x in unique_coor]
unique_index = [coor_tuple.index(x) for x in unique_coor]
```

Comment: I tried it but got the following output `(array([ 5,  9, 10, 12]), array([5, 3, 0, 2]), array([1, 2, 3, 2]))`, => 3 `10`'s, 2 `12` and `9`'s and 1 `5`. I think it might flatten the array before it computes the unique value as the indices also suggest.

Comment: Yes you are right, see my edit. I don't think that it is the fastest way to do what you want, but it works.