# Python 2.7, finding length of numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

So with my code, I'm analyzing the total number of pixels that are within the threshold of my values. However, it's very slow, and it all comes down to one line of code, basically bottle-necking the entire program. This code is simple, in that it splits the array up into the values so I can count the length, however, it brings the frames per second down from 30 to about 4.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from PIL import Image


camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (320,240)
rawCapture= PiRGBArray(camera)


for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format='bgr', use_video_port=True):
    data= frame.array

    lower=np.array([100, %0, 50], dtype='uint8')
    upper= np.array([250, 150, 150], dtype="uint8")

    thresh= cv2.inRange(data, lower, upper)
    data={tuple(item) for item in thresh} # this is the problem line.
    len(data)

    rawCapture.truncate(0)
    FPS=FPS+1
    New_time=time.time()-start
    if New_time> 10:
        print FPS/10, 'fps'
        New_time=0
        start=time.time()
        FPS=0
```

I feel like half the problem is that it is a loop (python hates loops), but I don't really know how to alter arrays. What's the 'pythonic' way of achieving this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by length?  It seems to me that you re trying to find the number of unique rows in your array, is that accurate?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: I wanted just anything that showed out, but this method appears to be working. If I could get individual pixel that would be brilliant but right now I'm just using what is working.

Comment: Hmmm. I am unfamiliar with the libary, but if `hresh= cv2.inRange(data, lower, upper)` is an array with values from `data` that are within your range, then you should be able to just use `hresh.shape`, no? I'm still not understanding why they need to be unique.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or even `thresh.size` for the total number of pixels

Comment: @MosesKoledoye even better... but notice this code is only looking at one axis. Honestly, I think this question could do with some clarification. I don't think it's just my unfamiliarity with the associated libraries.

Comment: It's a detection program. I don't want the size of the picture itself, nor how many total pixels. Just the pixels that are within the threshold. Those suggestions include pixels that have now been altered to (0, 0, 0). I want to know the pixels that are between the upper and lower values.

Comment: Try, then, `np.unique(data).size`

Comment: But that will also count pixels with are not within my threshold.

Comment: sorry, `np.unique(thresh).size`

Comment: That appears to return a value of one, and it is also an int, so it is impossible to count. I don't exactly know what went one there but yeah...

Comment: I realize now that you are working with some number of rows, which represent a single pixel, and three columns. Try to follow some of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array

Comment: So you are trying to find how many unique rows there are in `thresh`?  Try searching for SO questions on `unique rows`.

Comment: @DaveyBoy you want the length of the pixels or the pixels themselves (within the threshold)?

Comment: I think my code would require an additional for loop to be accurate. I do want individual pixels, not rows.

Also the method in that question uses arrays that are of integers, which will not work on this type of array.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye

How many pixels in the threshold is the aim. Rows sorta work for detection, but aren't optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the size of the picture itself, nor how many total
>   pixels. Just the pixels that are within the threshold.

`cv2.inRange` already does that, so the *set comprehension* will not be required:

> After calling `cv2.inRange`, a binary mask is returned, where white
>   pixels (255) represent pixels that fall into the upper and lower limit
>   range and black pixels (0) do not.

From the binary mask, the *in-range* values can be counted with:

```
thresh = cv2.inRange(data, lower, upper)
within_threshold = (thresh == 255).sum()
```

To get the pixels themselves, you can index the original `data` on the *in-range* binary mask:

```
data = data[thresh == 255]
```

Comment: That's it. But curious, why does it work? what does the 255 on it's own mean?

Comment: `cv2.inRange` returns values 255 or 0 at each pixel. 255 indicates values that are in the threshold.