# Take Unique of numpy array according to 2 column values.

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have Numpy array in python with two columns as follows :

```
time,id
1,a
2,b
3,a
1,a
5,c
6,b
3,a
```

i want to take unique time of each user. 
For above data i want below output.

```
time,id
1,a
2,b
3,a
5,c
6,b
```

That is, I want to take only unique rows. so, 1,a and 3,a will not repeat in the result. 
I have both the column as string datatype and have a very large 2-D array. 
one solution may be, i can iterate over all the rows and make a set. But that will be very slow. Please suggest an efficient way to implement it.

Comment: Do you have a numpy array or pandas data frame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find unique rows in numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of your array?

Comment: @hpaulj I have mentioned that array has 2 columns in 1st line. and data type is string. That is also mentioned.

Comment: @Psidom Clearly written that it is Numpy array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> b
[['1' 'a']
 ['2' 'b']
 ['3' 'a']
 ['1' 'a']
 ['5' 'c']
 ['6' 'b']
 ['3' 'a']]
```

You can do:

```
>>> np.vstack({tuple(e) for e in b})
[['3' 'a']
 ['1' 'a']
 ['2' 'b']
 ['6' 'b']
 ['5' 'c']]
```

Since that is a set comprehension, you loose the order of the original.

Or, to maintain order, you can do:

```
>>> c = np.ascontiguousarray(b).view(np.dtype((np.void, b.dtype.itemsize * b.shape[1])))
>>> b[np.unique(c, return_index=True)[1]]
[['1' 'a']
 ['2' 'b']
 ['3' 'a']
 ['5' 'c']
 ['6' 'b']]
```

Or, if you can use Pandas, this is really easy. Given the following DataFrame:

```
>>> df
  id  time
0  a     1
1  b     2
2  a     3
3  a     1
4  c     5
5  b     6
6  a     3
```

Just use `drop_duplicates()`:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
  id  time
0  a     1
1  b     2
2  a     3
4  c     5
5  b     6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go back to your original list format data and create a structured array, then determining the unique values is much easier.

```
a = [['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b'], ['3', 'a'],['1', 'a'],['5', 'c'], ['6', 'b'], ['3', 'a']]

tup = [tuple(i) for i in a]  # you need a list of tuples, a kludge for now

dt = [('f1', '<U5'), ('f2', '<U5')]  # specify a dtype with two columns

b = np.array(tup, dtype=dt)  # create the array with the dtype

np.unique(b)  # get the unique values
array([('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'a'), ('5', 'c'), ('6', 'b')], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<U5'), ('f2', '<U5')])

np.unique(b).tolist()  # and if you need a list, just change the array
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'a'), ('5', 'c'), ('6', 'b')]
```

Reference:  [Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

A combination of Joe Kingston and Jaime recommendations deal with views and the above can be simplified to the following.  Nicely, this option relies on view, a change of dtype to a structured array and a slice into the original array using the indices of the unique values in the structured view.

```
>>> dt = a.dtype.descr * a.shape[1]
>>> a_view = a.view(dt)
>>> a_uniq, a_idx = np.unique(a_view, return_index=True)
>>> a[a_idx]
array([['1', 'a'],
       ['2', 'b'],
       ['3', 'a'],
       ['5', 'c'],
       ['6', 'b']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

For Future readers a pure numpy way to drop duplicates based on a **specific** row/column:

```
x = np.array(
[[1,'a'],
[2,'b'],
[3,'a'],
[1,'a'],
[5,'c'],
[6,'b'],
[3,'a']])

print(x[np.unique(x[:,0], axis=0, return_index=True)[1]])

>>[['1' 'a']
   ['2' 'b']
   ['3' 'a']
   ['5' 'c']
   ['6' 'b']]
```

or more than one column:

```
print(x[np.unique(x[:,[0, 1]], axis=0, return_index=True)[1]])
```

Comment: this will drop duplicates based on a single column and NOT based on the values of both columns! (e.g. rows like `[1, "a"]` and `[1, "b"]` would be identified as duplicate... )

Comment: @raphael ??? That's literally what I said "..to drop duplicates based on a **specific** ...", This is just a generalized answer. do x[:, [0,1]] if you need to consider both

Comment: woha, sry, didn't realize that np.unique already considers all values in a row if you use `axis=0` ... I added it to the answer and will undo the down-vote once it's accepted!

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody still needs it, here's a one-liner :-)

Note that this requires all column values to have the same dtype!

```py
import numpy as np
a = [[1, "a"], [1, "b"], [1, "c"], [2, "a"], [2, "b"], [2, "c"],
     [1, "a"], [1, "b"], [1, "c"], [2, "a"], [2, "b"], [2, "c"]]

unique_a = np.unique(np.rec.fromrecords(a)).tolist()
>>> [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```