# Alternative way of mapping integer numpy arrays to unique identifiers in a vectorized way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer, uniqueidentifier

In some queueing and inventory problems the state of a system can be represented by 1d integer numpy arrays (with a constant length). Now I would like to map states to a unique single number/string to quickly identify them.

At the moment I'm using the following approach for this:

```
import numpy as np

#Example: state space consists of all integer arrays with 3 elements ranging from 0 to 4.
statespace      = np.indices([5]*3).reshape(3,-1).T 

#Obtain unique integers by converting to a number system with the smallest possible base. 
minvalues       = np.amin(statespace,axis=0)
maxvalues       = np.amax(statespace,axis=0)
base            = 1+np.max(maxvalues-minvalues)        
statecode       = np.power(base, np.arange(statespace.shape[1]))

def getStateCode(state):
    #Convert states to a unique integer by taking the dot product with statecode.
    return np.dot(state-minvalues,statecode)

#Obtain codes and sort them.    
codes = np.sort(getStateCode(statespace))  

def getStateIndex(state):
    #Searches for the state in the sorted vector with codes.
    statecodes  = getStateCode(state)
    return np.searchsorted(codes,statecodes).astype(int)
```

Now

```
state = np.array([0,0,0])
print(getStateIndex(state))
```

returns state index `0`.

For small to medium sized problems this approach works well and it is vectorized. However, for larger problems it suffers from integer overflow  especially if `base` is large.

This occurs in particular when some elements in the state space have larger ranges than others (for example, the first element could range from 0 to 100, while all other elements between 0 and 3, resulting in a base 101 system). Even for state spaces that can easily be stored in memory, this can result in integer overflow of `statecode`. Making `statecode` a 64bit integer only delays the problem.

Does anybody have an alternative (vectorized?) way to convert 1d integer arrays to a unique identifier without this problem? As these comparisons are carried out repeatedly for millions of states, the approach has to be fast. I've read about hash functions, but I'm a bit hesitant to use those because there is no guarantee of uniqueness.

Comment: Is the length the same for all states?

Comment: @dnalow Yes. I mention that now in the question.

Comment: *"Making `statecode` a 64bit integer only delays the problem."* - so what is the size of the largest state space you need to represent? If it's bigger than 2⁶⁴ then there's no way you can use single integers as unique identifiers. What do you want to use the identifiers for?

Comment: You can use a [mixed radix numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix), see numpy.ravel_multi_index and numpy.unravel_index. The unique identifier is essentially the linear index into the statespace array.

Comment: I was also just going to ask: Why not different bases per columns, but that is essentially what user6758673 means. I also think this way you get the smallest range of numbers possible for this countable set

Comment: Assuming that the total size of the state space is ≤ 2⁶⁴ you could use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/1461210) to map each unique row to an int64 index.

Comment: @ali_m I want to use the identifiers to obtain the index of a certain state in an array with costs/rewards. Each state makes random transitions to other states, and I need the indices to calculate the expected cost/reward. The example in the question already shows there can be more state codes than states.

Comment: @user6758673 thanks a lot. That works extremely well. To apply this to an array with multiple states, this can be used: `np.ravel_multi_index((state-minvalues).transpose().reshape(statespace.shape[1],-1), maxvalues-minvalues+1)`. In cases where not all states are included, one will still have to search a sorted list to get the correct indices.