# How to count distinct values in a combination of columns while grouping by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas data frame. I want to group it by using one combination of columns and count distinct values of another combination of columns.

For example I have the following data frame:

```
   a   b    c     d      e
0  1  10  100  1000  10000
1  1  10  100  1000  20000
2  1  20  100  1000  20000
3  1  20  100  2000  20000
```

I can group it by columns `a` and `b` and count **distinct** values in the column `d`:

```
df.groupby(['a','b'])['d'].nunique().reset_index()
```

As a result I get:

```
   a   b  d
0  1  10  1
1  1  20  2
```

However, I would like to count distinct values in a **combination of columns**. For example if I use `c` and `d`, then in the first group I have only one unique combination (`(100, 1000)`) while in the second group I have two distinct combinations: `(100, 1000)` and `(100, 2000)`.

The following naive "generalization" does not work:

```
df.groupby(['a','b'])[['c','d']].nunique().reset_index()
```

because `nunique()` is not applicable to data frames.

Comment: could you not simply create a column `f` as a combination of `c` and `d`?

Comment: @NilsGudat, yes I though about this approach but I was not sure if it is a correct way to go. I have the following concerns. I have numeric values in both columns, how should I construct unique values out of them? I could transfer them to strings and then concatenate strings but it might be too slow.

Comment: None of the answers worked for you? ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can create combination of values converting to `string` to new column `e` and then use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df['e'] = df.c.astype(str) + df.d.astype(str)
df = df.groupby(['a','b'])['e'].nunique().reset_index()
print (df)
   a   b  e
0  1  10  1
1  1  20  2
```

You can also use `Series` without creating new column:

```
df =(df.c.astype(str)+df.d.astype(str)).groupby([df.a, df.b]).nunique().reset_index(name='f')
print (df)
   a   b  f
0  1  10  1
1  1  20  2
```

Another posible solution is create tuples:

```
df=(df[['c','d']].apply(tuple, axis=1)).groupby([df.a, df.b]).nunique().reset_index(name='f')
print (df)
   a   b  f
0  1  10  1
1  1  20  2
```

Another numpy solution by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/2901002):

```
def f(x):
    a = x.values
    c = len(np.unique(np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))), return_counts=True)[1])
    return c

print (df.groupby(['a','b'])[['c','d']].apply(f))
```

**Timings**:

```
#[1000000 rows x 5 columns]
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30, size=(N,5)))
df.columns = list('abcde')
print (df)  

In [354]: %timeit (df.groupby(['a','b'])[['c','d']].apply(lambda g: len(g) - g.duplicated().sum()))
1 loop, best of 3: 663 ms per loop

In [355]: %timeit (df.groupby(['a','b'])[['c','d']].apply(f))
1 loop, best of 3: 387 ms per loop

In [356]: %timeit (df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).size().groupby(level=['a', 'b']).size())
1 loop, best of 3: 441 ms per loop

In [357]: %timeit ((df.c.astype(str)+df.d.astype(str)).groupby([df.a, df.b]).nunique())
1 loop, best of 3: 4.95 s per loop

In [358]: %timeit ((df[['c','d']].apply(tuple, axis=1)).groupby([df.a, df.b]).nunique())
1 loop, best of 3: 17.6 s per loop
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't stop the groupby at `'a', 'b'`, include everything you're looking at.

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).size()

a  b   c    d   
1  10  100  1000    2
   20  100  1000    1
            2000    1
dtype: int64
```

---

`unstack` to get a different view

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

---

to actually get at the information you're looking for

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).size().groupby(level=['a', 'b']).size()

a  b 
1  10    1
   20    2
dtype: int64
```

Says:
within the the group `a is 1; b is 10` there are 1 unique combinations of `c and d`.
within the the group `a is 1; b is 20` there are 2 unique combinations of `c and d`.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to concatenate columns, you can apply a function that counts the number of non-duplicates:

```
df.groupby(['a','b'])[['c','d']].apply(lambda g: len(g) - g.duplicated().sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your original concept...

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).d.nunique()

a  b   c  
1  10  100    1
   20  100    2
Name: d, dtype: int64
```

You can drop the `c` in the index and focus on just the information you want.

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).d.nunique().reset_index('c', drop=True)

a  b 
1  10    1
   20    2
Name: d, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think in you example you calculate unique values just in one column ("d")  and I want to be able to calculate unique combinations of values from several columns. So, my original example is more general.

Comment: That's the thing.  Using the group by that includes one of your columns and calculating `nunique` on the other one, does exactly that.

Comment: what if for ´a, b, c = 1, 10, 100´ I have 2 unique values of d and for ´a, b, c = 1, 10, 200´ I have 3 unique values of d. Now I should group by `a and b` again and sum up 2 and 3 to find out that for `a, b = 1, 10` I have 5 unique combinations of c and d.