# pandas speed up count unique elements in several groups df

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following data:

```
Out[6]: 

                 Src  Dst  Port  Application      Start        Date
0            0.0.0.0    1     1            1 2016-10-20  2016-10-20
1  00:00:0C:9F:F0:64   10     1            1 2016-10-20  2016-10-20
2  00:00:0C:9F:F0:65    3     1            1 2016-10-20  2016-10-20
3  00:00:0C:9F:F0:66   10     1            1 2016-10-20  2016-10-20
4  00:00:0C:9F:F0:67   42     1            1 2016-10-20  2016-10-20

In [7]: df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
Out[7]: 

Src            791215
Dst              2599
Port                1
Application        44
Start             335
Date               15
dtype: int64
```

I want to know the number of unique values that each source has each day. 
I wrote:
`df_day = df.groupby(['Src', 'Date'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()))`

but it is incredibly slow (it runs forever). The number of groups is quiet large  `791215 * 15`

Is there any way I can speed up this computation?

Comment: which pandas version are you using? actually there were some big performance improvements in the 0.19 release of pandas

Comment: `In [6]: pd.__version__
Out[6]: 
u'0.19.1'
`  The data is quiet big: `In [7]: df.shape
Out[7]: 
(10076686, 6)
`

Comment: why the nested apply? what is a unique __value__? the unique values for dst, port, application and start?

Comment: yes. For each couple (`Src, date`) I want to know the number of unique values of the other columns.  In other words for each day I want to know to how many different `Dst, Port,...` each ip has connected.

Comment: okay, i just checked your code, and now I know why you use the double apply. I just tried to use only one apply and a for loop to iterate over the columns.  On a small dataframe this is 15% slower. What may save time here, ist that you don't need to calculate the src - date unique values (which you still do, though you know the result beforehand). This takes for my small data frame roughly 50% of the clocktime

Comment: I fear I don't see something else here. Another idea could be to use spark? At least it sounds like a nicely parallelizable task. Additionally, you could try to parallelize your computations, which pandas unfortunately doesn't do.

Comment: thanks I'll have a look at other libraries. Apparently there isn't any easy solution with pandas

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40805769/2901002)