# Numpy intersect1d with array with matrix as elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, one of the shape `(200000, 28, 28)` and the other of the shape `(10000, 28, 28)`, so practically two arrays with matrices as elements.
Now I want to count and get all the elements (in the form `(N, 28, 28)`), that overlap in both arrays. With normal for loops it is way to slow, so I tryied it with numpys intersect1d method, but I dont know how to apply it on this types of arrays.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I will edit my question to make that clear

Comment: Are those numbers in the arrays in some interval maybe?

Comment: Yeah, they range from 0 to 255

Comment: You can use the approach in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

Comment: Basically this is a variation on the common 'unique row` question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the approach from [this question about unique rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

```
def intersect_along_first_axis(a, b):
    # check that casting to void will create equal size elements
    assert a.shape[1:] == b.shape[1:]
    assert a.dtype == b.dtype

    # compute dtypes
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * np.prod(a.shape[1:])))
    orig_dt = np.dtype((a.dtype, a.shape[1:]))

    # convert to 1d void arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    a_void = a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1).view(void_dt)
    b_void = b.reshape(b.shape[0], -1).view(void_dt)

    # intersect, then convert back
    return np.intersect1d(b_void, a_void).view(orig_dt)
```

Note that using `void` is unsafe with floats, as it will cause `-0` to be unequal to `0`