# Using numpy.unique on multiple columns of a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, uniqueidentifier

I am looking to use `numpy.unique` to obtain the reverse unique indexes of two columns of a `pandas.DataFrame`.

I know how to use it on one column:

```
u, rev = numpy.unique(df[col], return_inverse=True)
```

But I want to use it on multiple columns. For example, if the `df` looks like:

```
    0   1   
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   2   1
3   2   1
4   3   1
```

then I would like to get the reverse indexes:

```
[0,1,2,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one NumPy approach converting each row to a scalar each thinking of each row as one indexing tuple on a two-dimensional (for 2 columns of data) grid -

```
def unique_return_inverse_2D(a): # a is array
    a1D = a.dot(np.append((a.max(0)+1)[:0:-1].cumprod()[::-1],1))
    return np.unique(a1D, return_inverse=1)[1]
```

If you have negative numbers in the data, we need to use `min` too to get those scalars. So, in that case, use `a.max(0) - a.min(0) + 1` in place of `a.max(0) + 1`.

**Approach #2**

Here's another NumPy's views based solution with focus on performance inspired by [`this smart solution by @Eric`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41417343/3293881) -

```
def unique_return_inverse_2D_viewbased(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * np.prod(a.shape[1:])))
    return np.unique(a.view(void_dt).ravel(), return_inverse=1)[1]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [209]: df
Out[209]: 
    0   1   2   3
0  21   7  31  69
1  62  75  22  62  # ----|
2  16  46   9  31  #     |==> Identical rows, so must have same IDs
3  62  75  22  62  # ----|
4  24  12  88  15

In [210]: unique_return_inverse_2D(df.values)
Out[210]: array([1, 3, 0, 3, 2])

In [211]: unique_return_inverse_2D_viewbased(df.values)
Out[211]: array([1, 3, 0, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can convert columns to `strings` and then `sum`:

```
u, rev = np.unique(df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1), return_inverse=True)
print (rev)
[0 1 2 2 3]
```

As pointed [`DSM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167413/using-numpy-unique-on-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe#comment73409300_43167428) (thank you), it is dangerous.

Another solution is convert rows to `tuples`:

```
u, rev = np.unique(df.apply(tuple, axis=1), return_inverse=True)
print (rev)
[0 1 2 2 3]
```

Comment: Dangerous.  This would be unable to distiguish the row 11,2 from 1,12.