# PYTHON: How to merge equal element numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to merge an two equal element in an array, let say I am having an array like this

```
np.array([[0,1,1,2,2],
          [0,1,1,2,2],
          [0,2,2,2,2]])
```

I want to produce something like this if I am directing it right

```
np.array([[0,0,2,0,4],
          [0,0,2,0,4],
          [0,0,4,0,4]])
```

And this if I am moving it up

```
np.array([[0,2,2,4,4],
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,2,2,2,2]])
```

My current code simply loops through a normal list

```
    for i in range(4):
     for j in range(3):
         if mat[i][j]==matrix[i][j+1] and matrix[i][j]!=0:
             matrix[i][j]*=2
             matrix[i][j+1]=0
```

I prefer numpy and absence of loops if possible

Answer (score 1):

This task is deceptively difficult to do without loops!  You'll need a bunch of high-level `numpy` tricks to make it work.  I sort of fly through them here, but I will try to link to other resources where I can.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array), the best way to do row-wise comparison is:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,1,2,2],
              [0,1,1,2,2],
              [0,2,2,2,2]])

b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))

b

array([[[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]],
       [[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]],
       [[0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]]], 
       dtype='|V20')

b.shape
(3, 1)
```

Notice that the innermost brackets are not an additional dimension, but an `np.void` object that can be compared with things like [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

Still, getting the indices you want to keep isn't really easy, but here's the one-liner:

```
c = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[1, np.diff(np.unique(b, return_inverse = 1)[1])])
```

Eech.  It's kinda messy.  Basically you're looking for the indices where the lines change, and the first line.  Normally you wouldn't need the `np.unique` call and could just do `np.diff(b)`, but you can't subtract `np.void`.  `np.r_` is a shortcut for `np.concatenate` that's a bit more readable.  And `np.flatnonzero` gives you the indices where your new array isn't zero (i.e. the indices you want to keep)

```
c
array([0, 2], dtype=int32)
```

There, now you can use some fancy [`ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) math to do your addition:

```
d = np.add.reduceat(a, c, axis = 0)

d

array([[0, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

OK, now to add the zeros, we'll just plug that into an `np.zero` array using [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)

```
e = np.zeros_like(a)
e[c] = d
e

array([[0, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

And there we go!  You can go in other directions by transposing or flipping the matrix at the beginning and the end.

```
def reduce_duplicates(a):
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))
    c = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[1, np.diff(np.unique(b, return_inverse = 1)[1])])
    d = np.add.reduceat(a, c, axis = 0)
    e = np.zeros_like(a)
    e[c] = d
    return e

reduce_duplicates(a.T[::-1,:])[::-1,:].T  #reducing right

array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 4]])
```

I don't have `numba` so I can't test speed against the other suggestion (knowing `numba` it is probably slower), but it is loopless and numpy.

Answer (score 0):

A "vectorized" version of your function would be pretty messy, since the merges can happen at both even or odd indexes in each row/column, depending on preceding values in that row/column.

To illustrate, see how this vectorized version works on your (horizontal) example which happens to have all merges land on odd indexes:

```
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
>>> y=x==np.roll(x, 1, axis=1); y[:,1::2]=False; x*y*2
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 4]])
```

But if I shift one of the rows by 1, it no longer works:

```
>>> x2
array([[0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
>>> y=x2==np.roll(x2, 1, axis=1); y[:,1::2]=False; x2*y*2
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 4]])
```

I'm not sure what strategy I would take next, if it is possible to implement this in a vectorized fashion, but it wouldn't be very clean.

I would suggest using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) for something like this. It will keep your code readable and should make it faster. Just add the `@jit` decorator to your function and evaluate how much it improves performance.

**EDIT:** I did some timing for you. Also there is a small fix to your function to make it coincide with your example.

```
>>> def foo(matrix):
...     for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
...         for j in range(matrix.shape[1]-1):
...             if matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][j+1] and matrix[i][j]!=0:
...                 matrix[i][j+1]*=2
...                 matrix[i][j]=0
...
>>> from numba import jit
>>> @jit
... def foo2(matrix):
...     for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
...         for j in range(matrix.shape[1]-1):
...             if matrix[i][j]==matrix[i][j+1] and matrix[i][j]!=0:
...                 matrix[i][j+1]*=2
...                 matrix[i][j]=0
...
>>> import time
>>> z=np.random.random((1000,1000)); start=time.time(); foo(z); print(time.time()-start)
1.0277159214
>>> z=np.random.random((1000,1000)); start=time.time(); foo2(z); print(time.time()-start)
0.00354909896851
```