# How to sort rows of a binary-valued array as if they were long binary numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

There is a 2D numpy array of about 500000 rows by 512 values each row:

```
[
  [1,0,1,...,0,0,1], # 512 1's or 0's
  [0,1,0,...,0,1,1],
  ...
  [0,0,1,...,1,0,1], # row number 500000
]
```

How to sort the rows ascending as if each row is a long 512-bit integer?

```
[
  [0,0,1,...,1,0,1],
  [0,1,0,...,0,1,1],
  [1,0,1,...,0,0,1],
  ...
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure but the function "sorted" works to sort strings which are arrays of characters, maybe it works with integer arrays ?

Comment: @Orionss Bad idea. Don't bring python functions where numpy arrays are involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of converting to strings you can also use a `void` view (as from @Jaime [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/4427777)) of the data and `argsort` by that.

```
def sort_bin(b):
    b_view = np.ascontiguousarray(b).view(np.dtype((np.void, b.dtype.itemsize * b.shape[1])))
    return b[np.argsort(b_view.ravel())] #as per Divakar's suggestion
```

Testing

```
np.random.seed(0)

b = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10,5))
print(b)
print(sort_bin(b))

[[0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0]
 ..., 
 [1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1]]
[[0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0]
 ..., 
 [1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Should be much faster and less memory-intensive since `b_view` is just a view into `b`

```
t = np.random.randint(0,2,(2000,512))

%timeit sort_bin(t)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.09 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([[int(i) for i in r] for r in np.sort(np.apply_along_axis(lambda r: ''.join([str(c) for c in r]), 0, t))])
1 loop, best of 3: 3.29 s per loop
```

About 1000x faster actually

Comment: Smart one! Some noticeable improvement with `b[np.argsort(b_view.ravel())]`.

Comment: Thanks Divakar, I forgot `.flatten()` makes a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort them in a [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) way 512 times, starting with the right-most bit first.

1. Sort by last bit
2. Sort by second-last bit, stable (to not mess up results of previous sort)
3. ...
   ...
4. Sort by first bit, stable

---

A smaller example: assume you want to sort these three 2-bit numbers by bits:

```
11
01
00
```

In the first step, you sort by the right bit, resulting in:

```
00
11
01
```

Now you sort by the first bit, in this case we have two `0s` in that column. If your sorting algorithm is not stable it would be allowed to put these equal items in any order in the result, that could cause `01` to appear before `00` which we do not want, so we use a stable sort, keeping the relative order of equal items, for the first column, resulting in the desired:

```
00
01
11
```

Comment: You could probably use `np.lexsort` for this, but I'm not sure it would be faster than a string/void conversion.

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating a `string` of each `row` and then applying `np.sort()`

So if we have an `array` to test on:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1]])
```

We can create `strings` of each `row` by using [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
a = np.apply_along_axis(lambda r: ''.join([str(c) for c in r]), 0, a)
```

which would make `a` now:

```
array(['1010', '0010', '0011', '0011'], dtype='<U4')
```

and so now we can `sort` the `strings` with `np.sort()`:

```
a = np.sort(a)
```

making `a`:

```
array(['0010', '0011', '0011', '1010'], dtype='<U4')
```

we can then convert back to the original format with:

```
a = np.array([[int(i) for i in r] for r in a])
```

which makes `a`:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

And if you wanted to cram this all into one line:

```
a = np.array([[int(i) for i in r] for r in np.sort(np.apply_along_axis(lambda r: ''.join([str(c) for c in r]), 0, a))])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It just seems "wrong" to convert single bits to character bytes. Maybe [numpy.packbits()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html#numpy.packbits) each row to 64 uint8's and then use your method?

Answer (score 0):

This is slow but does the job.

```
def sort_col(arr, col_num=0):
# if we have sorted over all columns return array
if col_num >= arr.shape[1]:
    return arr

# sort array over given column
arr_sorted = arr[arr[:, col_num].argsort()]

# if the number of 1s in the given column is not equal to the total number
# of rows neither equal to 0, split on 1 and 0, sort and then merge
if len(arr) > np.sum(arr_sorted[:, col_num]) > 0:
    arr_sorted0s = sort_col(arr_sorted[arr_sorted[:, col_num]==0], col_num+1)
    arr_sorted1s = sort_col(arr_sorted[arr_sorted[:, col_num]==1], col_num+1)
    # change order of stacking if you want ascenting order
    return np.vstack((arr_sorted0s, arr_sorted1s))

# if the number of 1s in the given column is equal to the total number
# of rows or equal to 0, just go to the next iteration
return sort_col(arr_sorted, col_num + 1)



np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 4))
print(a)
print(sort_col(a))

# prints
[[0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
[[0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Edit. Or better yet use Daniels solution. I didn't check for new answers before I posted my code.