# Find unique pairs of array with Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm searching for a pythonic way to do this operation faster

```
import numpy as np
von_knoten = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4])
zu_knoten =  np.array([1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2])
try:
    for i in range(0,len(von_knoten)-1):
        for j in range(0,len(von_knoten)-1):
            if (i != j) & ([von_knoten[i],zu_knoten[i]] == [zu_knoten[j],von_knoten[j]]):
                    print(str(i)+".column equal " +str(j)+".column")
                    von_knoten = sp.delete(von_knoten , j)
                    zu_knoten = sp.delete(zu_knoten , j)
                    print(von_knoten)
                    print(zu_knoten)
except:
    print('end')
```

so I need the fastest way to get

```
[0 0 1 1 4]
[1 2 2 3 2]
```

from

```
[0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4]
[1 2 0 2 3 0 1 4 1 2]
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: The entries of the arrays are pairs. Like the first entry is 1 and 0.
So 1 and 0 are Pairs, therefor i want to delete the third entry of both arrays because 0 and 1 is the same pair.

Comment: Why are you using `try ... except`?  Are you expecting an exception?  And why are you using a bitwise operator `&` instead of the logical operator `and`?

Comment: Also, are you aware that you're skipping the last array entries?  Do you understand how ranges work in python?  Hint:  range(0, 5) is 0 through 4.  It excludes 5.

Comment: If speed is your concern, this is a classic example in which PyPy can give you a serious boost without touching the code.

Comment: Why was [4,2] chosen over [2,4] in the final output?

Comment: @Divakar i was wondering too why [4,2] choosen over [2,4]... :/

Comment: So, `[2,4]` is the correct output?

Comment: It should be the first instance of the repeated sets that are returned?

Comment: @Divakar yes it should be [2,4]. I've tested your code and it's really clever!

How you find that way to code in sense of vectorized? I'm really fascinated!
It's really realy fast

Comment: @Search898 Just some experience working with NumPy helped I guess :) If your problem has been solved, don't forget to accept the one that helped the most. You can also upvote solutions. More info on those here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: @DanielF I've not got your question. It should only find unique pairs without looking for the order

Comment: @Search898 Just so that we are clear on what accepting solutions mean on Stackoverflow terminology - It's done by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to the solution. Since, you haven't done this on your questions, I thought this could be instructive. An example image view here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png. Apologies if you were aware and needed more time before accepting, which is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments about your code; as-is, it does not do what you want, it shall print some stuff, did you even try to run it? Could you show us what you obtain?

- first, simply do a `range(len(von_knoten))`; this will do what you want, as `range` starts at `0` by default, and ends one step before the end.
- if you `delete` some items from the input lists, and try to access to items at end of them, you will likely obtain `IndexError`s, this before exhausting the analysis of your input lists.
- you do some `sp.delete` but we do not know what that is (neither do the code), this will raise `AttributeError`s.
- alas, please do not use `except:`. This will catch Exceptions you never dreamt of, and may explain why you don't understand what's wrong.

---

Then, what about using `zip` built-in function to obtain sorted two-dimensions tuples, and remove the duplicates ? Something like:

```
>>> von_knoten = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
>>> zu_knoten =  [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2]
>>> set(tuple(sorted([m, n])) for m, n in zip(von_knoten, zu_knoten))
{(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)}
```

I let you work around this to obtain the exact thing you're looking for.

Comment: hi, this is my result
`0.column equal 2.column
[0 0 1 1 2 2 2 3 4]
[1 2 2 3 0 1 4 1 2]
1.column equal 4.column
[0 0 1 1 2 2 3 4]
[1 2 2 3 1 4 1 2]
2.column equal 4.column
[0 0 1 1 2 3 4]
[1 2 2 3 4 1 2]
3.column equal 5.column
[0 0 1 1 2 4]
[1 2 2 3 4 2]
5.column equal 4.column
[0 0 1 1 4]
[1 2 2 3 2]
end`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build up a collection of pairs you haven't seen before.
You can use `not in` but need to check this either way round:

```
L = []
for x,y in zip(von_knoten, zu_knoten):
  if (x, y) not in L and (y, x ) not in L:
    L.append((x, y))
```

This gives a list of tuples

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

which you can reshape.

Comment: It will be faster (OP is concerned about performance) if `L` is a `set` (`in` and `not in` are `O(1)` operations on sets). This will, however, require to call `sorted` on `L` if OP cares about order.

Comment: True - I went for simplest... but they did ask for fastest too.

Comment: @DeepSpace Calling `sorted` makes no sense.  If order matters, then you simply maintain the set and the list in parallel, adding a new pair to both if it's missing from the set.  There is no need for this to be anything other than O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized output -

```
def unique_pairs(von_knoten, zu_knoten):
    s = np.max([von_knoten, zu_knoten])+1
    p1 = zu_knoten*s + von_knoten
    p2 = von_knoten*s + zu_knoten
    p = np.maximum(p1,p2)
    sidx = p.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    ps = p[sidx]
    m = np.concatenate(([True],ps[1:] != ps[:-1]))
    sm = sidx[m]
    return von_knoten[sm],zu_knoten[sm]
```

Sample run -

```
In [417]: von_knoten = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4])
     ...: zu_knoten =  np.array([1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2])

In [418]: unique_pairs(von_knoten, zu_knoten)
Out[418]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.unique` and the `void` view method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array/16973510#16973510)

```
def unique_pairs(a, b):
    c = np.sort(np.stack([a, b], axis = 1), axis = 1)
    c_view = np.ascontiguousarray(c).view(np.dtype((np.void,
                                          c.dtype.itemsize * c.shape[1])))
    _, i = np.unique(c_view, return_index = True)
    return a[i], b[i]
```