# Finding ONLY Unique Coordinates in List

Tags: python, list, numpy, unique

I have a list of coordinates like

```
list_cor = 
    [[4190091.4195999987, 7410226.618699998], 
    [4190033.2124999985, 7410220.0823], 
    [4190033.2124999985, 7410220.0823], 
    [4190035.7005000003, 7410208.670500003], 
    [4190033.2124999985, 7410220.0823], 
    [4190022.768599998, 7410217.844300002]]
```

I need to get only these values:

```
[[4190091.4195999987, 7410226.618699998], 
[4190035.7005000003, 7410208.670500003], 
[4190022.768599998, 7410217.844300002]]
```

Tried `numpy.unique()` but it adds this item `[4190033.2124999985, 7410220.0823]`, which I don't need.

Comment: The thing that can be confusing is that `np.unique(list_cor, axis=0)` gets you _the array with duplicates removed_; it does not _filter the array to elements that are unique in the original array_.

Answer (score 8):

Use `numpy.unique` with `axis` and `return_counts` parameters:

```
arr, uniq_cnt = np.unique(list_cor, axis=0, return_counts=True)
uniq_arr = arr[uniq_cnt==1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there :

```
coords=[ x+1j*y for (x,y) in list_cor] # using complex; a way for grouping
uniques,counts=np.unique(coords,return_counts=True)
res=[ [x.real,x.imag] for x in uniques[counts==1] ] # ungroup
```

For :

```
[[4190022.7685999982, 7410217.8443000019],
 [4190035.7005000003, 7410208.6705000028],
 [4190091.4195999987, 7410226.6186999977]]
```

Comment: Seems like `return_counts=True` is only possible with Numpy >= 1.9 ,though.

Comment: @B. M. Your code works, however I haven't used `numpy` yet and according to @tobias_k comment what means **Numpy >= 1.9**?

Comment: @PavelPereverzev I meant that this feature was added in Numpy version 1.9. You can check your version with `import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)`

Comment: @tobias_k checked version, it is 1.9.3 , so everything's working

Answer (score 1):

For older version of numpy that don't have the `return_counts` parameter, you could help yourself with `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> list_cor = np.array(list_cor)  # assuming list_cor is a numpy array
>>> counts = collections.Counter(map(tuple, list_cor))
>>> counts_arr = np.array([counts[tuple(x)] for x in list_cor])
>>> list_cor[counts_arr == 1]
array([[ 4190091.4196,  7410226.6187],
       [ 4190035.7005,  7410208.6705],
       [ 4190022.7686,  7410217.8443]])
```

Comment: hmm, gives me `TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index`

Comment: @PavelPereverzev That's weird. Note that I was assuming that your `list_cor` is a numpy array, as you tagged the question as `numpy`. Does it not work with an array?

Comment: Yes, after conversation to an array everything works

Answer (score 1):

In simple pure python basic types:

```
# transform to tuples
list_cor=[tuple(c) for c in list_cor]
# transform back after using set to select unique elements only
list_cor_unique=[list(l) for l in list(set(list_cor))]
# create a copy
list_cor_more_than_once = [i for i in list_cor]
# drop all the elements appearing only once
[list_cor_more_than_once.remove(tuple(l)) for l in list_cor_unique if tuple(l) in list_cor]
# finally, keep the uniques not appearing more than once
list_cor_unique=[l for l in list_cor_unique if (tuple(l) in list_cor) and (not (tuple(l) in list_cor_more_than_once)) ]
```

Pros:

- no external libraries
- would work for higher dimension coordinates

Comment: unfortunately it gives one value I don't need to be in list_cor_unique: `[4190033.2124999985, 7410220.0823]`

Answer (score 1):

I like using a dictionary to keep track of counts:

```
>>> counts = {}
>>> for coordinate in list_cor:
...     coordinate = tuple(coordinate) # so it can be hashed and used as dict key
...     counts.setdefault(coordinate, 0) # add coordinate to dict
...     counts[coordinate] += 1 # increment count for coordinate
...
```

You then have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
>>> counts
{(4190091.4195999987, 7410226.618699998): 1, (4190033.2124999985, 7410220.0823): 3, (4190035.7005000003, 7410208.670500003): 1, (4190022.768599998, 7410217.844300002): 1}
```

You can then use list comprehension to create a list of unique coordinates:

```
>>> [list(coordinate) for coordinate, count in counts.items() if count == 1]
[[4190091.4195999987, 7410226.618699998], [4190035.7005000003, 7410208.670500003], [4190022.768599998, 7410217.844300002]]
```

If you're fine leaving the coordinates as tuples, you can replace `list(coordinate)` with `coordinate`.

Comment: I also thought about using dictionaries but thought that there is a faster way to get unique values instead of running more than one cycle. Anyway your code works right!

Comment: I'm not sure what the faster way would be. The only algorithm I can think of that wouldn't iterate again would be to create two sets: a 'found' set and a 'found again' set. For each coordinate, if it's already in the 'found' set, add it to the 'found again' set; otherwise add it to the 'found' set. Then subtract the 'found again' set from the 'found' set to create a 'found once' set.

Comment: got it. Well, I think that two sets will not save much time so dictionaries are simple and fast enough for me.