# In Python. I have a list of ND arrays and I want to count duplicate arrays in order to calculate an Average for each Duplicate array value

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, counter, average

I have a list of ND arrays(vectors), each vector has a `(1,300)` shape.
My goal is to find duplicate vectors inside a list, to sum them and then divide them by the size of a list, the result value(a vector) will replace the duplicate vector.
For example, `a` is a list of ND arrays, `a = [[2,3,1],[5,65,-1],[2,3,1]]`, then the first and the last  element are duplicates.
their `sum` would be :`[4,6,2]`, 
which will be divided by the size of a list of vectors, `size = 3`.

Output: `a = [[4/3,6/3,2/3],[5,65,-1],[4/3,6/3,2/3]]`

I have tried to use a `Counter` but it doesn't work for ndarrays.

What is the Numpy way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy 1.13 or higher, this is pretty simple:

```
def f(a):
    u, inv, c = np.unique(a, return_counts = True, return_inverse = True, axis = 0)
    p = np.where(c > 1,  c / a.shape[0], 1)[:, None]
    return (u * p)[inv]
```

If you don't have 1.13, you'll need some trick to convert `a` into a 1-d array first.  I recommend @Jaime's excellent answer using `np.void` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/4427777)

How it works:

- `u` is the unique rows of `a` (usually not in their original order)
- `c` is the number of times each row of `u` are repeated in `a`
- `inv` is the indices to get `u` back to `a`, i.e. `u[inv] = a`
- `p` is the multiplier for each row of `u` based on your requirements.  `1` if `c == 1` and `c / n` (where `n` is the number of rows in `a`) if `c > 1`.  `[:, None]` turns it into a column vector so that it broadcasts well with `u`

return `u * p` indexed back to their original locations by `[inv]`

Comment: It works now , after I converted!  `[[  1.33333333   2.           0.66666667]
 [  5.          65.          -1.        ]
 [  1.33333333   2.           0.66666667]]`  Could you please add an explanation on how it works?

Comment: I also converted `a` into `np.array` in order for it to work like this: `a = np.array([[2,3,1],[5,65,-1],[2,3,1]])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy unique , with count return count

```
 elements, count = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

Return Count allow to return the number of occurrence of each element in the array

The output is like this ,

```
(array([[ 2,  3,  1],
        [ 5, 65, -1]]), array([2, 1]))
```

Then you can multiply them like this :

```
(count * elements.T).T
```

Output :

```
array([[ 4,  6,  2],
       [ 5, 65, -1]])
```