# Numpy 2d set diff

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In numpy is it possible to make a difference between this 2 arrays:

```
[[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]
 [0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3]]


[[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2]
 [0 1 2 3 0 2 3 0 1 2]]
```

to have this result

```
[[1 2]
 [1 3]]
```

?

Comment: Can you explain the pattern behind the difference?

Comment: from what I can tell, the result is the columns that are present in the first array, but missing from the second one. So a column wise equivalent of python's set subtraction

Comment: Yes, I tought it is obvious. Consider both arrays as, associations between 2 lists: (0,0), (0,1) ...(2,3) for the first array, (0,0),(0,1)..(2,2) for the secodn array. I want to find the difference between these associations, which is (1,2) and (1,3)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way. You can also use `numpy.unique` for a similar solution (easier in v1.13+, see [Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)), but if performance is not an issue you can use `set`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]])

B = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]])

res = np.array(list(set(map(tuple, A.T)) - set(map(tuple, B.T)))).T

array([[2, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```

Comment: ah, I can't see how unique can help, since I have 2 arrays with different shapes. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @sergiuz, Try using `axis` argument or transposing the matrices via `A.T`, `B.T`.

Answer (score 1):

We can think 2D array as 2 times of 1D array and using **numpy.setdiff1d** to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
a=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
b=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]]
a = np.array(a).T
b = np.array(b).T
A = [tuple(t) for t in a]
B = [tuple(t) for t in b]
set(A)-set(B)
Out: {(1, 1), (2, 3)}
```