# I can't delete duplicated rows in a list with python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray

I can't delete duplicated rows in a list  with python, what's is the problem ? how can I solve this ? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Use `np.unique()` with `axis` param.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

Comment: Please always post code, data, and error messages as text directly here on SO, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the same element in list,  you can do it this way :

```
for i in reversed(range(len(list))):
    if l[i] in l[0:i]:
        l.pop(i)
```