# How to not insert the same combination of values in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a matrix that is 6x3 containing different probabilities.

My rows in this case has 3 values, corresponding to the probability of my sample ending up belonging to a certain class.

What I'm trying to do is to get every of the 3 different classes for my 6 samples. 
I'm worried that I might end up with duplicates.

I've noticed that every element in `lista` contains 6 values. Is there a simple way for me to get rid of possible duplicates ?

```
for combination in itertools.product(*probability):
    q1 = np.prod((combination))
    lista.append(q1)
    print(combination)
    i = i+1
print(i)
print(np.sum(lista))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if not item in list: list.append(item)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `set(lista)` will remove any duplicate values

Example:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,1,2]
new_list = set(lista)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

**Edit**: As per your comment, use `itertools` and `groupby()` to remove duplicate lists within a list as such;

```
import itertools

lista = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [3,4,5]]
new_list = list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(lista))
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Got one question, it seems like this removes items that are the same, but I have a list containing multiple values, for example list((0,1 , 0,2 , 0,3 , 0,4 , 0,5 , 0,6),(0.1, 0.2 , 0.3 , 0.4 , 0.5 , 0. 7). I do not wish it to remove these objects, only that it removes two lists that are identical, not the objects in it.

Comment: @A.Maine I've added another suggestion based on what you're asking, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this implementation! Will accept answer as soon as I can