# pandas.factorize with custom array datatype

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Let's start off with a random (reproducible) data array -

```
# Setup
In [11]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(7,2))
    ...: a[2] = a[0]
    ...: a[4] = a[1]
    ...: a[6] = a[1]

# Check values
In [12]: a
Out[12]: 
array([[5, 0],
       [3, 3],
       [5, 0],
       [5, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [6, 8],
       [3, 3]])

# Check its itemsize
In [13]: a.dtype.itemsize
Out[13]: 8
```

Let's view each row as a scalar using custom datatype that covers two elements. We will use `void-dtype` for this purpose. As mentioned in the docs -

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface) and in [stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/), it seems that would be -

```
In [23]: np.dtype((np.void, 16)) # 8 is the itemsize, so 8x2=16
Out[23]: dtype('V16')

# Create new view of the input
In [14]: b = a.view('V16').ravel()

# Check new view array
In [15]: b
Out[15]: 
array([b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'],
      dtype='|V16')

# Use pandas.factorize on the new view
In [16]: pd.factorize(b)
Out[16]: 
(array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1]),
 array(['\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
        '\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
        '\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'],
       dtype=object))
```

Two things off factorize's output that I could not understand and hence the follow-up questions -

1. The fourth element of the first output (=0) looks wrong, because it has same ID as the third element, but in `b`, the fourth and third elements are different. Why so?
2. Why does the second output has an object dtype, while the dtype of `b` was `V16`. Is this also causing the wrong value mentioned in `1.`?

A bigger question could be - Does `pandas.factorize` cover custom datatypes? From docs, I see :

> values : sequence A 1-D sequence. Sequences that aren’t pandas objects
>   are coerced to ndarrays before factorization.

In the provided sample case, we have a NumPy array, so one would assume no issues with the input, unless the docs didn't clarify about the custom datatype part?

> System setup : Ubuntu 16.04, Python : 2.7.12, NumPy : 1.16.2, Pandas :
>   0.24.2.

**On Python-3.x**

> System setup : Ubuntu 16.04, Python : 3.5.2, NumPy : 1.16.2, Pandas :
>   0.24.2.

Running the same setup, I get -

```
In [18]: b
Out[18]: 
array([b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
       b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'],
      dtype='|V16')

In [19]: pd.factorize(b)
Out[19]: 
(array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1]),
 array([b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
        b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
        b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
        b'\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'],
       dtype=object))
```

So, the first output off `factorize` looks alright here. But, the second output has object dtype again, different from the input. So, the same question - Why this dtype change?

#### Compiling the questions/tl;dr

With such a custom datatype :

1. Why wrong `labels`, `uniques` and different `uniques` dtype on Python2.x?
2. Why different `uniques` dtype on Python3.x?

Answer (score 8):

As for why `V16` is coerced to `object`, many functions in `pandas` convert data to one of the data types the internal functions can handle, [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L183). If the data type is not in the list, it becomes an object – and pandas doesn't convert the result back into the original dtype, it appears.

Regarding the discrepancy between Python 2 and Python 3: There's only one pandas codebase for both, so why do they give different results?

Turns out that Python 2 uses the string type (which are just arrays of bytes) to represent your data¹, and Python 3 the bytes type. The effect of this is that Python 2 uses a [`StringHashTable`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L182) for the factorization and Python 3 uses a [`PyObjectHashTable`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L183), and the `StringHashTable` gives incorrect results in your case. I believe that this is because the strings in the `StringHashTable` are assumed to be zero-terminated, which is not the case for your strings – and indeed, if you only compare the rows up to the first zero byte, the first and fourth row look identical.

Conclusion: It's a bug, and we should probably file an issue for it.

¹ More detail: This call to [`ensure_object`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.24.x/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L129) returns an array of strings in Python 2, but an array of bytes in Python 3 (as can be seen by the `b` prefix). Correspondingly, the hashtable chosen [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.24.x/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L228) is different.