# np.where checking also for subelements in multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two multidimensional arrays with the same second dimension. I want to be sure no element (i.e., no row) of the first array is also a row of the second array.

To do this I am using `numpy.where`, but its behaviour is also checking for sub-elements in the same position. For example consider this code:

```
x = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [4,0,6,9]])
z= np.array([[0,1,2,3], [5, 11, 6,98]])
for el in x:
    print(np.where(z==el))
```

It prints:

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
(array([1]), array([2]))
```

where the first result is due to the first arrays being equal, the second is because the both `z[1]` and `x[1]` have `6` as third element. Is there a way to tell `np.where` to return only indexes of strictly equal elements, i.e. `0` in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man I haven't had a chance to link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/4427777) answer since `np.unique` added an `axis` parameter.  Credit to @Jaime

```
vview = lambda a: np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1])))
```

Basically, that takes the "rows" of your matrix and turns them into a 1-d array of views on the raw datastream of the rows.  This lets you compare rows as if they were single values.

Then it's fairly simple:

```
print(np.where(vview(x) == vview(z).T))
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
```

Representing that the 1st row of `x` matches the first row of `z`

If you only want to know if rows of `x` are in rows of `z`:

```
print(np.where(np.isin(vview(x), vview(z)).squeeze()))
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

Checking times compared to @mujjiga on big arrays:

```
x = np.random.randint(10, size = (1000, 4))

z = np.random.randint(10, size = (1000, 4))

%timeit np.where(np.isin(vview(x), vview(z)).squeeze())
365 µs ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [i for i, e in enumerate(x) if (e == z).all(1).any()]  # @mujjiga
21.3 ms ± 1.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.where((x[:, None] == z).all(-1).any(-1))  # @orgoro
20 ms ± 767 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So about a 60x speedup over looping *and* slicing, probably due to quick short-circuiting and only comparing 1/4 the values

Comment: That is no-every-day code: I like it. Let me recap to see if I get it right. `ascontigous()` returns a contiguous array representation in memory, the `view` method basically tells how to reformat that array with no specified type (`np.void`) and I assume `a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]` is the byte size of one row. I don't get why the transpose when comparing though.

Comment: At some point `view` started keeping dimensions, so the output of that snippet for `(n, m)` input is `(n, 1)` now instead of `(n,)`.  So, that means I can trade `[:, None]` and `[None, :]` that's usually needed for broadcasting for a simple transpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
[i for i, e in enumerate(x) if (e == z).all(1).any()]
```

#### Test case:

```
x = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [4,0,6,9], [4,0,6,19]])
z= np.array([[4,0,6,9], [0,1,2,3]])

[i for i, e in enumerate(x) if (e == z).all(1).any()]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1]
```

Comment: Using vectorized approach will speed this up dramatically - see my answer

Comment: Actually in my test your answer is only about a 10% speedup over this.  And my void view method is about 60x faster than either.

Comment: This is a good answer and I like the simplicity, getting also the indexes of the first vector would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

Where simply returns the indices of your condition - here it's element wise equal

### Answer

You can find the duplicates using vectorized operations:

```
duplicates = (x[:, None] == z).all(-1).any(-1)
```

### Get Values

To get the duplicates values use masking

```
x[duplicates]
```

in this example:

```
duplicates = [True False]

x[duplicates] = [[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

### Logic

1. expanding the array `[:, None]`
2. find only full row matches `all(-1)`
3. return rows that have at least one match `any(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, for 2D arrays, something like the following might be useful. I think you'd have to be careful with check `ee==0` in floating point arithmetic.

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
# we are trying to find the row in aa which is equal to bb
bb = np.asarray([0,1,2,3])
cc = bb[None,:]
dd = aa - cc
ee = np.linalg.norm(dd,axis=1)
idx = np.where(ee==0)
```

Comment: This is not robust.  if `a = [1,2,3]` and `b=[1,1,4]`, `(a-b).sum()==0` is true, but even though the entries don't match

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Let me see if I can modify it. Edit: replaced np.sum by np.linalg.norm.

Comment: I mean, it works, but that's a ton of computational overhead even compared to looping.  Square roots are sloooooow