# Python : Most efficient way to count elements of long list 1 in long list 2 ? (list comprehension is really slow)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have many tuples (e.g. `(0, 1)`) in two pretty long lists `list_0`and `list_1`of size ~40k elements. I need to count the tuples of `list_0` also in `list_1`.

The following statement with list comprehension takes ~ 1 min and I need to do this multiple times, so I am looking for something more efficient :

```
len([element for element in list_0 if element in list_1])
```

What could be more efficient ?

To reproduce :

```
elements_0 = 200*[0]+50*[1]+150*[2]
elements_1 = 100*[1]+150*[2]+150*[1]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(elements_0), list(elements_1)]).T
list_0 = [item for sublist in df.groupby(0)[0].apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x.index, 2))) for item in sublist]
list_1 = [item for sublist in df.groupby(1)[1].apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x.index, 2))) for item in sublist]

print(len([pair for pair in list_0 if pair in list_1])) # Long
```

Comment: Check your variable names, this code isn't reproducible. Looks like you might be mixing up `elements_0`, `list0`, and `list_0`

Comment: Yes I corrected it, thanks

Comment: [The `numpy` answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890422/np-where-checking-also-for-subelements-in-multidimensional-arrays/64891214#64891214)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use

```
pd.Series(list_0).isin(list_1).sum()
```

Output:

```
22300
CPU times: user 14.8 ms, sys: 20 µs, total: 14.8 ms
Wall time: 14.1 ms
```

which should give the same answer with:

```
len([element for element in list_0 if element in list_1])
```

which gives:

```
22300
CPU times: user 13.8 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 13.8 s
Wall time: 13.8 s
```

Also `merge` and query:

```
s = df.reset_index()
print(len(s.merge(s, on=[0,1])
  .query('index_x > index_y')
))
```

with output:

```
22300
CPU times: user 13.4 ms, sys: 15 µs, total: 13.4 ms
Wall time: 12.3 ms
```

Comment: A typo in variable names - corrected. Thanks

Comment: @Vincent see updated answer with performance comparison.

Comment: @Vincent updated with a slightly faster solution.

Comment: @Daniel F pointed this solution in numpy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890422/np-where-checking-also-for-subelements-in-multidimensional-arrays/64891214#64891214 By any chance, could you please compare it with the same setup as the previous 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Make `list_1` a set first then find the elements that are in it:

```py
list_1_set = set(list_1)
print(len(element for element in list_0 if element in list_1_set))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to sort these two lists first. Then you can use two pointers for these two lists. Compare whether the tuples on the two pointers match or not, then update the pointer to next tuple in the list. This should take O(n). Please correct me if there is anything wrong. Thanks.