# efficient way to make an array unique by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

Assuming we have a two dimensional array like the following:

```
array1 = np.array([[1,4,3, 64356,5435,434],
                   [11,46,3, 7356,585,74],
                   [51,406,3, 769,5435,24],
                   [12,45,5, 656,135,134],
                   [112,475,5, 656,1385,134],
                   [13,46,  5, 656,1385,19]])
```

the row 4 and 5 are not unique in terms or their 2,3,4 columns , for which we want to drop one of them.
Is there an efficient way to drop rows of an array and make its rows unique in terms of selected columns of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array

Comment: @QuangHoang but that does not allow selectivity by columns.

Comment: work on `array1[:,your_select_column]` and get the index?

Comment: If using pandas is an option. You can turn your array to a dataframe and use `drop_duplicates` function which accepts `subset` argument which is used to select columns

Comment: @QuangHoang np.unique(array1[:,your_select_column], axis=1) returns unique rows of those columns. how retrieve indecisive then. There should be also an approach to drop non-unique ones randomly for example

Comment: @S.Mohsensh that sounds better, could you show an example of it?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(array1).drop_duplicates(your_select_column)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in pure numpy:

```
_, idx = np.unique(array1[:,[2,3,4]], axis=0, return_index=True)
array1[sorted(idx)]
```

Output:

```
array([[    1,     4,     3, 64356,  5435,   434],
       [   11,    46,     3,  7356,   585,    74],
       [   51,   406,     3,   769,  5435,    24],
       [   12,    45,     5,   656,   135,   134],
       [  112,   475,     5,   656,  1385,   134]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to pandas and back as suggested by S.Mohsen

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[1,4,3, 64356,5435,434],
                   [11,46,3, 7356,585,74],
                   [51,406,3, 769,5435,24],
                   [12,45,5, 656,135,134],
                   [112,475,5, 656,1385,134],
                   [13,46,  5, 656,1385,19]])
                   
df = pd.DataFrame(data=array1)
print(df)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[2,3],inplace=True)
print(df)

array2=df.values
print(array2)
```

Output:

```
     0    1  2      3     4    5
0    1    4  3  64356  5435  434
1   11   46  3   7356   585   74
2   51  406  3    769  5435   24
3   12   45  5    656   135  134
4  112  475  5    656  1385  134
5   13   46  5    656  1385   19

    0    1  2      3     4    5
0   1    4  3  64356  5435  434
1  11   46  3   7356   585   74
2  51  406  3    769  5435   24
3  12   45  5    656   135  134

[[    1     4     3 64356  5435   434]
 [   11    46     3  7356   585    74]
 [   51   406     3   769  5435    24]
 [   12    45     5   656   135   134]]
```