# How to delete elements repeated in a 2_D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following question which I want to solve with numpy Library.
Let's suppose that we have this 'a' array

```
a = np.vstack(([10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 20] ,[10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 20]))
```

As output we have

```
[[10 10 20 20 30 10 40 50 20]
 [10 20 10 20 30 10 40 50 20]]
with the shape (2, 9)
```

I want to delete the elements repeated vertically in our array so that I have as result:

```
[[10 10 20 20 30 40 50]
 [10 20 10 20 30 40 50]]
```

In this example I want to delete the elements ((0, 5), (1, 5)) and ((0, 8), (1, 8)). Is there any numpy function that can do the job ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done with:

```
np.unique(a, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22941699/2476977), you could do the following.

```
np.hstack({tuple(row) for row in a.T}).T
```