# Merge two numpy arrays, drop duplicates, and unmerge it

Tags: python, numpy, split

I have two `numpy` arrays: `X` with shape of `(n, 16928)`, and `y` with shape of `(n,1)`.

I would like to merge the two arrays, drop the duplicated rows if any, and "unmerge" the result back in separate arrays `X` and `y`. I was able to merge two arrays, but how do I split them back?

**Edit**

Here is an example:

```py
X = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    [3,4,5,2,1,4,5],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
])

y = np.array([
    [2.],
    [3.],
    [4.],
    [2.],
    [3.],
    [4.],
])
```

**Expected result**

```py
>>> X, y
(array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]),
 array([[2.],
        [3.],
        [4.],
        [3.],
        [4.]]))
```

As you can see, while there might be duplicated rows in the resulting `X`, the augmented rows `[X | y]` are unique. I tried `np.unique(np.hstack((X,y)))`, but this does not returns desirable results.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "drop duplicates"? Ideally include a smaller [mre] in your question

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75478510/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) **with test data** demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Not really, no. your "expected output" still has duplicate rows in them.

Comment: I edited your question in an attempt to clarify -- of course, please revert if I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: "but how do I split them back" Well, when you look at the merged data, **what is the rule that tells you** which part came from X and which part came from y?

Comment: Thank you @PierreD, yes this is the problem I was facing. Thank you for rephrasing it.

Comment: Is the answer below solving your problem then?

Comment: Hey! Yes it worked!! It literally halved memory consumption lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, we need to do a little roundtrip via `pandas`, which has a `.drop_duplicates()` to drop duplicated rows. While there is a method `np.unique()`, it is element-wise and *sorts* the array (costly, often unwanted). (Edit: as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069948/758174), there is a `numpy` way to get the unique rows; but it still sorts the array -- I still prefer `pandas` approach for this).

Thus:

```py
import pandas as pd

Xnew, ynew = np.split(
    pd.DataFrame(np.c_[X, y]).drop_duplicates().to_numpy(),
    [-1], axis=-1)

>>> Xnew
array([[1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.],
       [2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.],
       [3., 4., 5., 2., 1., 4., 5.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.]])

>>> ynew
array([[2.],
       [3.],
       [4.],
       [3.],
       [4.]])
```